# double arithmetic and equality in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

Here's an oddity (to me, at least). This routine prints true:

```
double x = 11.0;
double y = 10.0;
if (x-y == 1.0) {
    // print true
} else {
    // print false
}
```

But this routine prints false:

```
double x = 1.1;
double y = 1.0;
if (x-y == 0.1) {
    // print true
} else {
    // print false
}
```

Anyone care to explain what's going on here? I'm guessing it has something to do with integer arithmetic for `int`s posing as `float`s. Also, are there other bases (other than `10`) that have this property?

Comment: Isn't this the usual double/floating point error? You simply can not compare doubles using ==. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: @theomega: thanks for the link, but this still doesn't explain why the first case works.

Comment: It does. You can represent 1.0 in binary, but you can't represent 0.1. Well ok you can but not with double. That's why (11.0-10.0) == 1.0 but (1.1-1.0) != 0.1 when you're using double. You can take a look at BigDecimal if you need such features.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java floating point arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/java-floating-point-arithmetic)

Comment: This document should clarify many questions you might have about floating point: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.0 has an exact binary representation.  0.1 does not.

perhaps you are asking why 0.1 is not stored as a mantissa of 1 and an exponent of -10?  but that's not how it works.  it's not a decimal number plus an exponent, but a binary number.  so "times 10" is not a natural thing.

sorry, maybe the last part is unclear.  it's better to think of the exponent as a shift of bits.  no shift of bits will convert an infinite sequence like 0.1 (decimal) into a finite one.

Comment: @PengOne: Yes, `0.5` is exactly representable, as well as `0.25` and `0.75`, or `0.125`.

Comment: @paulo: yep, i just checked those as well. thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: i'm afraid you're mistaken.  just because it sometimes works out doesn't mean it's ok.  computers work in binary.  that means that everything is based around the number 2.  so 0.1 and 0.2 are going to have a very closely related representation (because one is a multiple of 2 of the other).  so it's likely that subtracting one from the other gives a "round" result.  but that doesn't mean that either has a finite representation in binary.

Comment: @Andrew Learning and then getting rewarded... might become addicted to this kind of treatment... Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**
I stand corrected by Andrew. Thank you!

Java follows IEEE 754 with a Base of 2, so it cannot represent 0.1 correctly (it is aprox. `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` or `1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 * 2^-4` in IEEE) which you can find out based on the binary representation of the double like this (bit `63` = sign, bits `62-52` = exponent and bits `51-0` being the mantissa):

```
long l = Double.doubleToLongBits(0.1);
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(l));
```

I just got carried away by the results and I thought for a moment that the floats in Java are working with a Base of 10 in which case it would have been possible to represent 0.1 just fine.

And now to hopefully clear the things once and for all, here's what goes on:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal1 = new BigDecimal(0.1d);
BigDecimal bigDecimal2 = new BigDecimal(1.1d - 1.0);
BigDecimal bigDecimal3 = new BigDecimal(1.1d);
BigDecimal bigDecimal4 = new BigDecimal(1.0d);
System.out.println(bigDecimal1.doubleValue());
System.out.println(bigDecimal2.doubleValue());
System.out.println(bigDecimal3.doubleValue());
System.out.println(bigDecimal4.doubleValue());
System.out.println(bigDecimal1);
System.out.println(bigDecimal2);
System.out.println(bigDecimal3);
System.out.println(bigDecimal4);
```

Outputs:

```
0.1
0.10000000000000009
1.1
1.0
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
0.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
1
```

So what happens? 1.1 - 1.0 is equivalent to:
`1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625 - 1` (Java can't represent 1.1 precisely) which is `0.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625` and this is different than the way Java represent 0.1 internally (`0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`)

If you're wondering why the result of the subtraction is being displayed as `0.10000000000000009` and the "0.1" is displayed as it is, have a [look over here](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.programmer/2007-01/msg00453.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for **why**, which I think @andrew answered.

Comment: this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/java-floating-point-arithmetic/1661624#1661624 in the thread you link to explains why you are mistaken here.

Answer (score 0):

This comes up in currency calculations all the time. Use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you need exact numerical representation at the cost of not having hardware enabled performance, of course.