# Java Number Format Dilemma

Tags: java

I am having a problem with this code!
I am trying to run the code in java but the answer seems pretty weird.

```
float a=0.1F;
float b=0.2F;
if((a+b)==0.3){
System.out.println("True");
}
else{
System.out.println("False");
}
```

The answer is : False
But theoretically it should be return True. 
The function returns True if we use values of a and b like 0.15 and 0.15 or 0.05 and 0.25.
I am confused.
I have read somewhere that languages like Java/JavaScript implements IEEE-754 number formatting! If so, then what is this formatting and what is wrong with the code? Is there anyway to change the number format?

Comment: Would this help ? (a+b)==.3F ?

Comment: Possible Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289361/double-arithmetic-and-equality-in-java

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that question earlier. The problem is with the binary form of representation of numbers.

Comment: Yes it is problem with binary representation of floating part (right to decimal point) . Therefore it is suggested not to use == on floating  nunbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The precision difference between floats (`a+b`) and doubles (`0.3`) is causing the condition to be false. You could instead use `(a+b)==0.3F`. i.e.

```
float a = 0.1F;
float b = 0.2F;
if ((a + b) == 0.3F) {  // notice the "F"
    System.out.println("True");
} else {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

```
True
```

---

***EDIT***: In this case, even if you use `double`s the condition will be `false`:

```
double a = 0.1;
double b = 0.2;
if ((a + b) == 0.3) {
    System.out.println("True");
} else {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

```
False
```

Printing `0.1 + 0.2` will reveal why (the number cannot be represented perfectly):

```
0.30000000000000004
```

Comment: This could not work. The data loss because of converting 10 base to 2 base can also make condition false.

Comment: O.K. I forgot to mention f with 0.3.

Comment: What if all the variables are declared as double. Then compile and run and see the answer is false!!!

Comment: Try running the program in the question using the numbers a=0.15 and b=0.15 and don't declare the number as 0.3F then run the program and tell me the output!!!

Comment: @AnkurSharma. This is because .1 is not .1 , its treated as .9998888 something by computer, .2 is not .2 it is .198876 something.. Thats y the differences

Answer (score 1):

`(a + b)` is a float, whereas 0.3 is a `double`. You should compare it with the same type:

```
if ((a + b) == 0.3F) {
```

Comment: Try running the program by taking values of a=0.15 and b=0.15 and then check the output!!!

Answer (score 1):

simply add *f* to the end of the number to make the compiler differentiate between a `double` and a `float`:

```
float a=0.1F;
float b=0.2F;
if((a+b)==0.3f){
System.out.println("True");
}
else{
System.out.println("False");
}
```

UPDATE:

see this similar question too:

- [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)

where the best answer states you should check loat ewuality using:

```
if(Math.abs((a+b) - 0.3F) < epsilon)
```

where epsilon is a very small number like 0.00000001, depending on the desired precision.

Comment: Forget f! run the program with all the variables declared as double!

Comment: @ankurSharma that wont work. As .1 /.2 /.3 they do not have exact binary representation. And it is advisable not to use == on float and double.

Comment: Yeah! That's what the problem with IEEE-754 number representing scheme. Its the problem in JavaScript too!
Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Never compare Float/Double with == sign.

This could not work even if you put 'f' after number. The problem here is not format, it is data loss. The data loss happens because of converting 10 base to 2 base can also make condition false.

Answer (score 0):

```
float a=0.1F;
float b=0.2F;
if((a+b)==0.3){
System.out.println("True");
}
else{
System.out.println("False");
}
```

.3 by default is a double type. You do see it as .3 ,but for computer its exact value is .2999998... something. Hence the difference.

If you explicitly tell compiler that .3 is float then your analogy will hold.

So

```
float a=0.1F;
float b=0.2F;
if((a+b)==0.3F){
System.out.println("True");
}
else{
System.out.println("False");
}
```

Follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289361/double-arithmetic-and-equality-in-java) to satisfy your thirst for "double" issues

Comment: Try compiling the program declaring all of the variables as double instead of float and then tell me what do you get!

Comment: @ankurSharma i know about that .1 / .2 /.3 is not exact in float nor double. Are we playing some pop quiz?

Comment: but the program works perfectly for numbers declared as .15!
What is the best way to compare the floating/double precision numbers?
Or it is better to avoid their comparison!

Comment: @Ankursharma this gives a good overview of approaches to use and things to avoid. Personally I'll always usr BigDecimal if i got to ever do comparison or manipulations on floatings.. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896013/manipulating-and-comparing-floating-points-in-java