# Adding floating-point values, result unexpected

Tags: java, floating-point

I want to add two huge floating values but the result I am getting is a little off putting. Let me explain with an example:

```
String bi = "32323222.02";
float spend=0.00f;
spend = (Float.parseFloat(bi));

String si = "23232322.32";
float spend1=0.00f;
spend1 = (Float.parseFloat(si));

float spendSum=0.00f;
spendSum= spend+spend1;

System.out.println(spendSum);
```

Now the result for this is `5.5555544E7` whereas I want an answer like `55555544.34`.  Any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong with an example will be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point arithmetic not producing exact results in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java)

Comment: You know that `5.5555544E7` and `55555544.34` are the same numbers? The E stands for 'times 10 to the power n'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

floating point are not exact. This is because there are infinite number of rational numbers in any range, but you only have finite number of bits to represent them.

If you want exact, you should use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

More info on the floating point issue can be found at this [a bit complex] article: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

**EDIT**: Thanks to @ComplicatedSeeBio for his comment, I didn't notice the result is way off. His answer mentions why the difference is 20% off. However, even without "programming bugs" - you will still not get the result you are expecting due to the floating point issue.

Comment: This is generally correct but does not explain the 20% wrong answer. One floating-point addition is not 20% wrong unless you are using denormal numbers. If you aren't using denormals, you can expect one operation to be something like 0.0001% correct, give or take one significant digit.

Comment: It should be mentioned, however, that a `double` would at least be able to express the precision he's asking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
spend1 = (Float.parseFloat(bi));
```

You probably mean to parse `si` here. This explains the result you get: your program adds `32323222.02` to `32323222.02`.

Comment: @justin3250 Now that you have edited your question, amit's answer applies (and your question is a duplicate of a hundred identical floating-point question that get asked each day on StackOverflow).