# Arithmetic expression calculates 6.135157E-6 instead of zero

Tags: java, android, math, zero

I have the below code somewhere in my app

```
float private myMethod(float c){
    result = (float) (c+273.15);
}
```

When "c" gets the value something like -273.1455 the result is something very near to zero like 0.0044.

But when it gets the value -273.15 i get this instead of zero: 6.1035157E-6

Why does this happen?

Comment: Isn't 6.1035157E-6 even closer to zero than 0.0044?

Comment: I think something wrong with your calculation of c before the call of this function.

Comment: @Karthik , yes it is but i want this value to be an output to user. So it is better to show 0 instead of this. Also if i change the code to result = (float) (-273.15 + 273.15) it calculates to zero. Isn't that strange

Comment: @Yury , in debug mode i see that c is -273.15 when it is passed as parameter to myMethod. So i can't see why that happens

Comment: It depends on the float operation results. Using `result = (float) (-273.15 + 273.15)` will result in compile time optimization, so zero. Whereas `(float)(c+273.15)` uses floating point instructions of cpu, so it results in such small errors. you could use some math functions to use required precision.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point arithmetic not producing exact results in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java)

Comment: ...and many other questions (speaking of which -- is there any way we can maintain a FAQ of the most commonly-asked questions? Not so much for users, as for moderators&others to use to locate them.)

Comment: @JasonS sometimes you ask a question but you don't have a clue about the answer. When i asked this question i didn't know it had to do with floating point arithmetic. So how could i know what kind of topic to search for? So it is inevitable for duplicates to exists.

Comment: @miako -- absolutely -- it's not a criticism of you; if your question is closed (as I believe it should be), that's not a negative thing, it's just the convention for this website: we mark questions as duplicates of other questions so that readers have the advantage of seeing other previously asked questions on the same topic.

Comment: @JasonS i see your point. i am new here so i don't know well how it works. you are right, it is good to point out when duplicates exists. and now i see that the title of my question is not good because it's not easy for someone to find out if it is of the subject he is searching for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that 273.15 is a double, not a float, and neither of them can represent 273.15 exactly. However, since they have different precision they will round actually store different numbers. When the addition is done the c is converted to a double which will be able store the float representation of 273.15. So now you have two doubles with almost the same value and the difference will be non zero.

To get "more predictable" result, use 273.15f to ensure you have floats through the calculations. That should solve this problem but what you need to do is to read up on binary floating point arithmetics and how that differs from decimal arithmetic that we are taught in school.

[Wiki on floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) is a good place to start.

Comment: Yes it has to do sth with floating arithmetics. But i enter the variable like this `in_text = Float.parseFloat(etOne.getText().toString());
tvOne.setText(Float.toString(myMethod(in_text,d)));`. Why does it gets double instead of float?

Comment: +1.  Because 273.15 can't be expressed exactly in floating point, the `double` representation has to be more accurate than (and therefore different to) the `float` representation.  This question is a great illustration of the difference that the type of a literal can make.

Comment: @miako - Roger is referring to the literal in the code, where you write `(c+273.15)`.  A literal that contains a decimal point, but not the F on the end will be understood as a `double` by the compiler.

Comment: @DavidWallace And yes that solved the problem. Correct. I really should read about this. If you have any good post just tell me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Floating point calculations in computers are not accurate. You should read something about floating point arithmetics to prevent such errors.

Comment: So i understand it's sth with floating arithmetic as everyone say. I didn't know before about these issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the value, but with the display to the user.

I'm assuming you are converting it into a String. The way this is done is detailed in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)

To Display a correct value use the NumberFormat class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Example :

```
NumberFormat formater = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
formater.format(myMethod(-273.15))
```

Now you should get 0.

Comment: I did as Roger Lindsjo said and it worked. Now it displays 0. The correct code was `result=(float) (c-273.15F);` and it worked. When i write a decimal number without declaring it float explicitly, then by default by the system is double. But i am going to need your information for another problem that i had. I am going to need the NumberFormat class.

Comment: Even if you have 273.15F, it is not guaranteed to be 0. Compiler optimizations may make it something other than 0.

Comment: Why is that? Both values are float and they have the exact same representation of the same number. So i guess it can only be zero.

Comment: Actually not all floats can be "exactly" represented by the a binary representation. You can read up on how this is done. However, the main point is - if you are writing 273.15, since it cannot be represented absolutely accurately, it can be stored as 273.15000004252 or 273.15000023623 (just examples ). So if you subtract, you may get 2.4263E-8. This is just the nature of floating point computations.

Comment: but the floating point system will always represent it the same way, no matter if it's accurate or no. the difference is if you choose 32-bit (float) or 64-bit (double). I think a different representation of a number in float, comes when you cast from double to float instead of declaring it float.

Comment: you are right in case you hardcode 273.15f. However, in most cases it will come from some arithmetic operation and not hardcoded value. The way the compiler optimizes addition/subtraction/multiplication/string conversion can result in inaccuracies.