# Java Double increment

Tags: java, ieee-754

I have a double var

```
public double votes(){
    double votexp = 0;

      for(Elettore e:docenti.values()){
        if(e.getVoto()==true)          //everytime this is true increment by 1
        {
            votexp+=1.0;
        }   
    }
    for(Elettore e:studenti.values()){
        if(e.getVoto()==true)         //everytime this is true increment by 0.2
        {
            votexp+=0.2;
        }
    }
    for(Elettore e:pta.values()){
        if(e.getVoto()==true)        //everytime this is true increment by 0.2
        {
            votexp+=0.2;
        }
    }
    return votexp;
}
```

In my case the variable shoud be incremented to 2.6 but votexp returns 2.6000000000000005
how can i fix this by using the same double var and return a double precision number ?

Comment: exact duplicate of _so_ many questions about floating point precision.  TL;DR version - you can't represent 2.6 exactly in IEEE754 floating point format.

Comment: Similar question: [Floating point arithmetic not producing exact results in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how could i find out where the 0.000000005 sneaks in and maybe avoid that ?

Comment: @LucianEnache: You'd be best off waiting until you're done, and then trying to deal with it. See my (updated) answer. But again: Fast computer floating point numbers (like IEEE 754 and the like) sacrifice a **very** small amount of inaccuracy for speed, that's just the way they are.

Comment: @Alnitak: Actually, you can (or at least, it looks that way to me; I'm no guru!). It seems to be one of the intermediate values where the inaccuracy is being introduced.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/ suggests otherwise, showing the mantissa as a recurring binary fraction.  Likewise 0.2

Comment: @Alnitak: Now, *that* link goes in my tools list. Nifty! Glad I said I wasn't a guru. :-) But at least you can get the significance down to the point where the `toString` ignores it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are accumulating a rounding error.  The simplest thing to do is to use an `long` (or `int` and only use a double at the end. (Or a BigDecimal and double at the end, but this is overly complicated)

```
public double votes() {
    long votexp = 0;
    for (Elettore e : docenti.values())
        if (e.getVoto())          //everytime this is true increment by 1
            votexp += 10;
    for (Elettore e : studenti.values())
        if (e.getVoto())         //everytime this is true increment by 0.2
            votexp += 2;
    for (Elettore e : pta.values())
        if (e.getVoto())        //everytime this is true increment by 0.2
            votexp += 2;
    return votexp / 10.0;
}
```

---

```
double a = 26 / 10.0;
System.out.println(a);
```

prints

```
2.6
```

As the Double.toString() "knows" values can be imprecise, it will do a small amount of rounding. This rounding is limited so the result of operating on two `double` can have an error too large to hide.  If you round your last result correctly, the error will be small enough it won't cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try using java.math.BigDecimal class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to round the result, floating point numbers in Java (and basically every other environment) are **not** perfect, and sometimes small inaccuracies creep in.

If you're dealing with *decimal* numbers, there's [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which can precisely represent what you've shown (it just can't precisely represent *other* things, like `1 / 3`).

Alternately, you can multiply by 10, use `Math.round`, and divide by `10` if the problem isn't with the actual end value, but with inaccuracies that have crept in during the time you've built up that value. That **happens** to be case with 2.6 built up like this:

```
double n = 0;

n += 1;
n += 0.2;
n += 1;
n += 0.2;
n += 0.2;

System.out.println("n = " + n);     // "2.6000000000000005"
n = (double)Math.round(n * 10) / 10;
System.out.println("n = " + n);     // "2.6"
```

...but I don't think there's a guarantee that it will necessarily be the case with all values. (I'm not a floating point guru.)

**Or** just worry about it when you do the output, by truncating the output result to the appropriate level of precision.

Comment: _very_ small imprecisions - if "2.6" was the distance from the earth to the sun then the error is approximately equal to the size of one gnat's ass.

Answer (score 0):

Some numbers cannot be represented by double-precision floating point format exactly. Looks like an intermediate number in your calculation has this flaw, which is included in the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
(double)Math.round(value * 10) / 10
```

but you will never get the good result by doing addition of doubles like this