# Java Modulo operator

Tags: java, modulo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

When using the modulo operator in java I'm not getting the number I expect to get.

Heres what I'm doing:

```
double input = 5.59;
System.out.println("Output: " + (input % 2));
```

I expect to see 1.59 as the result however it is printing out 1.5899999999999999. Any clue as to why this may be?

Comment: This comes from floating point inaccuracy, [here is a great SO answer explaining exactly what is happening.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2100502/874257)

Comment: Ok, this is a multi multi duplicate (IEEE754, float, etc.). Let us a minute to find it...

Comment: Thanks @JosiahHester I'll read up on it. Do oyu know a way I may be able to fix this. I need it for a make change program for my grade 11 programming class. It is supposed to convert a number to exact change.

Comment: Another similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java with answers which may help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes from floating point inaccuracy, [here is a great SO answer explaining exactly what is happening.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100502/874257)

If you want it to round out the number you need to use formatting like this:

```
double input = 5.59;
System.out.format("Output: %.2f%n", (input % 2));
```

- The "%" tells the formatter to replace itself with the first numeric argument. You can add as many of these as you want.
- The ".2" tells the formatter to format the number with two places after the decimal.
- The "f" just tells the formatter it is a floating point number.
- The "%n" is a new line character appropriate to the platform running the application. You should always use "%n", rather than "\n".

[Here is some good documentation for all this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for description provided after edit

Comment: Thanks soo much :P I was trying to get this working for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of precision of Double. You need to format it to achieve your desired output.

```
double input = 5.59;
System.out.println("Output: " + new DecimalFormat("00.00").format(input % 2));
```

It will print Output: 1.59