# Why Number.prototype.toPrecision() returns weird results with precision greater than 16 in Chrome and Firefox and not in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, precision

I know that in Javascript the maximun and minimun safe numbers are of precision 16 
(tested in Chrome):

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER → 9007199254740991
Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER → -9007199254740991
```

However Number.prototype.toPrecision() allows numbers greater than 16, until 21. In that range the results are wierd (wierd = everything I don't understand right now):

```
6.789.toPrecision(21) → "6.78899999999999970157" /*¿Why this "70157" ending in Chrome(34.0.1847.137) and Firefox(29.0.1)?*/
2.345.toPrecision(21) → "2.34500000000000019540" /*¿Why this "19540" ending in Chrome and Firefox?*/
```

IE11(11.0.99) returns as expected:

```
6.789.toPrecision(21) → "6.78900000000000000000"
2.345.toPrecision(21) → "2.34500000000000000000"
```

- ¿Is this a bug in the JavaScript engines of Chrome(V8) and
  Firefox(SpiderMonkey)?
- ¿Is IE11 JavaScript engine (Chakra) better in
  it's Number.prototype.toPrecision() interpretation?

Comment: The length of the maximum exactly-representable integer does not tell anything about floating-point precision.

Comment: Opera's Presto engine does not do any rounding as well, so it looks IE is the odd one out again.

Comment: Yes, as usual IE is the odd one, but, can it be that this time IE is both, the odd one and correct one?

Comment: ¿Is this a bug? ¿How can I report it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number.prototype.toFixed: amazingly correct in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166098/number-prototype-tofixed-amazingly-correct-in-internet-explorer)