# Filter angular works incorrect on IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to use the filter number in angularjs follow

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number.

I have 2 values

- value A: 7007823424.91
- value B: 7945

and I want to multiply A and B, after that use the number filter for result. Something likes that:

```
Result = A * B

{{Result | number : 2}}
```

The Result must be displayed on form : 55,677,157,110,909.**95**

But when we open this form via IE10. The Result is 55,677,157,110,909.**96**.

I don't know why. Please help me to give your idea about this bug.

Thank you so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166098/number-prototype-tofixed-amazingly-correct-in-internet-explorer looks like it might be the reason for this behavior.