# System.out.printf() for float datatype

Tags: java, printf

I've a very short code snippet here:

```
public class FormatFloat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float x = 12.345f;
        System.out.printf("%18.7f%s", x, "\n");
        System.out.printf("%18.8f%s", x, "\n");
        System.out.printf("%18.10f%s", x, "\n");
        System.out.printf("%18.15f%s", x, "\n");
    }    
}
```

I'd supposed the output to be

```
        12.3450000
       12.34500000
     12.3450000000
12.345000000000000
```

But I'm getting

```
        12.3450003
       12.34500027
     12.3450002670
12.345000267028809
```

Can anybody tell me the reason behind it?

Comment: This is a duplicate (I'll look for the correct answer in a second). In the meantime, visit http://floating-point-gui.de/ for an answer.

Comment: `float` type precision is only 7-8 decimal digits. You may want `double` type for higher precision.

Comment: @nhahtdh: that won't remove the problem, it'll just make it slightly less visible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point arithmetic not producing exact results in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java)

Comment: @nhahtdh: from the above code it seems to be only 6 decimal place precision. Isn't it?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Well, yes it won't remove the problem. Just that it produces more reasonable-looking output.

Comment: If you actually /need/ the precision of your example and aren't too concerned about performance, you could look at `java.math.BigDecimal`.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: Not just looking, but the mantissa for `float` is 24 bits, which translate to around 7 decimal digits of precision (24 * log 2 / log 10 > 7).

Comment: @nhahtdh: okay. I just asked as you told above 7-8

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: Fixed the figure with actual calculation

Comment: this question could have a better title. any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem regards the IEEE 754 binary floating point representation.

Please see [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/) link for a complete description of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
double x = 12.345;
System.out.printf("%18.7f%n", x);
...
```

float precision is too low