# Split number to equal parts where the last part is equal or lower to the rest

Tags: java, math, filesplitting

I have a file that I want to split into 100 pieces.
The file size is 257019 bytes.
When running my splitter code below I get 99 parts with a size of 2545 byte and the last 100'th part is 5064 byte.

I need help to figure out how to make the first 99 parts having the same size and the last 100'th part having the leftover bytes that is equal or lower then 2545.

```
int partSize;
for(partSize=1 ;partSize< 257019; partSize++){
   if((int) Math.ceil(257019 / partSize) == 100){
     break;
   }
}

int totalparts = (int) Math.ceil(257019 / partSize); // =100
```

Comment: have you tried `Math.ceil(257019.0 / partSize) == 100)`?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the linux/gnu `split` command?

Comment: Im in win7 eclipse doing this, how can I add the .0, Double conversion.

Comment: ((double) length) / partSize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int fileSize = 257019;
int partSize = Math.ceil( ((double)fileSize) / 100);
int lastPacket = 257019 - (99 * partSize);
```

In this case:

```
int partSize = 2571;
int lastPacket = 257019 - 254529 = 2490 < 2571
```

The original problem with your code:

```
(int) Math.ceil(257019 / partSize) == 100
```

is that `257019 / partSize` is evaluated before `Math.ceil` is evaluated. If you divide an integer by an integer, the result is automatically an integer. The default behavior of an integer is to omit everything but the decimal itself, so it will automatically "`Math.floor()`" it.

Answer (score 3):

```
int partSize = totalSize / 100;
if ((totalSize % 100) != 0) {
    partSize++;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what it does compared to @bas answer that worked grate

Comment: if partSize cannot be fully divided by 100, it will leave a remainder. The `modulus` (`%`) operator checks if there is a remainder. If there is a remainder, then your `partSize` will need to be one size larger (since the last packet does otherwise not fit). This is a valid and working approach, though unnecessary technical imho.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic doesn't return exact results. You might end up with rounding errors. Integer arithmetic is fast and precise.

Comment: With that comment isn't @bas answer only wrong if I was to use the decimal value of the floating point [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java)

Comment: `%` works with integers, so there would be no need for the `(double)` conversion. The double conversion in my original answer would only be able to cause errors if the value of fileSize is extremely large. The size that does not yet exist on harddisks.