# Why java division give some incorrect exponential value

Tags: java

I write below code in java

```
double scale=1.0;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    scale=scale/10;
}
System.out.println(scale);
```

Now out put of this is 
**1.0000000000000002E-6**
which seems to be incorrect, but if I loop 5 times then output is correct as below
**1.0E-5**

Can any body tell me why this is and how can I remove this.

Comment: your code loops 6 times

Comment: Have a [read about it here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1661273/2024761).

Comment: I think the OP is syaing that if the 6 is edited to 5, the output is different?  Anyway, it's FP, so neither answer is particularly 'incorrect'.

Comment: We should seriously think about renaming `double` and `float` to `inexact` and `approximate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `floating point` precision problem. Use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.

```
    BigDecimal scale=BigDecimal.ONE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        scale = scale.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
    }
    System.out.println(scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because even 0.1 is not representable as an exact double value. These errors sum up and show in the result.

Answer (score -3):

change `i` initialization.

```
double scale=1.0;
for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
    scale=scale/10;
}
System.out.println(scale);
```

now our code will enter the for for values i = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], its 5 times

Comment: No, that's not correct :( Try it.

Comment: This isn't the issue. The issue is with floating point arithmetic.