# Float sum in java

Tags: java, sum

This is a simple add operation between two float:

```
float a = 3.9F;
float b = 2.95F;
Log.i("Operation","sum: "+String.valueOf(a+b));
```

This return me the following output:

```
11-26 15:02:15.680: I/Operation(18403): sum: 6.8500004
```

How can I obtain the correct value(6.85) ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java.

Comment: Also take a look at [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) provided in `java` api.

Comment: There's always an estimation while using Float, same thing with Double. You shall approximate to a number of decimal. Try BigDecimal instead if you need result, DecimalFormat like andrew Schuster says if you only need printing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `DecimalFormat` class.

**Example**

```
DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
Log.i("Operation", "sum: " + decFormat.format(a + b));
```

If you want to ensure that there are always going to be two decimal places, i.e: `2.90` or `2.00`, then you can do something like:

```
DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
Log.i("Operation", "sum: " + decFormat.format(a + b));
```

Comment: The number 12.90 is also correctly represented?

Comment: It's a simple fix: `##.##` would represent `12.9`. If you insist on the `.90`, then you could have `##.00`.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
String val = format.format(1.2223F+1.4334F);
System.out.println(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use format method of System.out, so that you can decide the specific output format:

```
float a = 3.9F;
float b = 2.95F;
System.out.format("%.2f", a + b);
```

Output will be:

```
6.85
```

In here, as you can guess, %f takes float type of argument and .2 between % and f characters means you want output of this float argument with 2 decimal numbers.