# Can someone explain to me why 0.15 - 0.10 = 0.049?;

Tags: java, math

so wandering...
i got this code

```
double Restant = 0;
Restant = 0.15 - 0.10;
```

and it gives me
0.049999999
can someone explain me why it does that?
and now weird manipulation just before that.

Comment: floating point arithmetic is not accurate

Comment: binary representations of floating point numbers is limited and are inaccurate approximations, doing math on these numbers compounds those inaccuracies.

Comment: 0.1 cannot be represented exactly in binary, it would be infinitely repeating so it is approximated. See also [*"Is floating point math broken?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Jon Skeet answers:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java

Comment: If you're using floating point, you NEED to understand floating point round-off. (For example, there is no exact representation of either 0.10 or 0.15 in binary floating point.)

Comment: Math.round(Restant*100.0)/100.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point is not accurate. Use a threshold value to decide if a particular result is "close enough" to be considered equal. E.g.

```
double EPSILON = 0.0001;
double expected = 0.05;
double actual = 0.15 - 0.10;
boolean isEqual = Math.abs(actual - expected) < EPSILON;
```

Or, just use Java's BigDecimal class

Answer (score 1):

The result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the characteristic feature of floating-point computation. Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Comment: BigDecimal is not always the right answer. It's more expensive to process, among other things. Fixed-point (scaled ints) is often preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike fixed point numbers, floating point numbers will some times (safe to assume "most of the time") not be able to return an exact representation of a number. This is the reason why you end up with 11.399999999999 as the result of 5.6 + 5.8.

If you want a fixed point arithmetic, use BigDecimal instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the number of fraction digits according to you needs.The following will give the expected result:

System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Restant));