# Typecasting processed float value to int reduces the actual value

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

In C++, **floor(9099.96 *100.0)** is giving me the answer as **909995**. I am expecting 909996.

I am not able to think of explanations here. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Because floating point is never exact unless every number is a power of 2.  And not always then.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results

Comment: @GabeSechan: 3.0 is exact and not a power of two.

Comment: @rici I meant the fractional part is a multiple of 2.  But to be picky, 3.0 won't always work either, if the exponent on the other number is so big it falls out into the error.

Comment: @GabeSechan: 3.0 is always exact (as is 100.0), but the exact product of 3.0 or 100.0 with some other exact number might not be representable (because the exact representation has more than 52 bits.) I think that's what you meant.

Comment: @rici Yeah, we both understand what we're talking about, and we're both right for how we were interpreting what we were talking about.  Any whole number is always exact if it fits within the mantissa because the fractional part (the .0) is a negative power of two.

Answer (score 3):

This is the proper result: according to [IEEE754 calculator](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), the value of `9099.96` is represented as `9099.9599609375` in `double`. After multiplication by `100` you get `909995.99609375`. Taking `floor` gives you `909995`.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew even small floating point values gets approximated.

Comment: @sandy: *Not* approximating them would require infinite memory.

Comment: @sandy Only integers small enough to stay entirely within the bits mantissa are represented exactly. Even "simple" fractions such as `0.1` are inexact. For example, adding `0.1` to itself ten times in a loop does *not* produce a number that is equal to `1`. You get a value that's really, really close, but a small error would remain.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - that's not quite true.  0.5, for instance, is exactly representable in both single- and double-precision.

Answer (score 0):

Try ceil. It will always round the the next greatest number, which in this case will give you 909996. You may also want to look at the round function.

Comment: Thanks.But reading from above shared link, I think Ceil fails for other numbers. For example ceil(9099.95 *100.0) gives you 909996.