# Am getting the value in jsp as different value rather than i entered

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Am getting the value in jsp as 2.2222222E7. but i gave input 22222222. how to resolve it? AM using double data type . please give me your suggestions to resolve my issue. can i resolve using javascript? how can i?

jsp page:

```
    <table id="payout" class="display" style="float:left; width: 100%;border-radius:  
       5px 5px 5px 5px;
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #666666;-moz-box-sizing: none;" border=1  
           data="${payout}">

                    <thead style="color: red">
         <tr>
                    <td class="heading">Charge</td>
                    <td class="heading">Cost Before Discount</td>
                    <td class="heading">After Plan Discount</td>
                    <td class="heading">After Booking Discount</td>


             </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      <c:forEach items="${payouts}" var="payout" varStatus="row">
                <tr>
                     <td >Base Cost</td> 
                     <td>${payout.baseCost.costBeforeDiscount}</td>
                     <td>${payout.baseCost.afterPlanDiscount}</td>
                     <td>${payout.baseCost.afterBookingDiscount}</td>

                </tr>
       </tbody>

        </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
```

Comment: where is the code that takes input and what portion of this code relates to output ?

Comment: Quick note on why you should NOT use double for currency - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results

Comment: The value isn't wrong.  You just haven't specified how you wanted it formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use number format in td tag

```
        <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

                            <table id="payout" class="display" style="float:left; width: 100%;border-radius: 
                 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                        box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #666666;-moz-box-sizing: none;" border=1  data="${payout}">

                            <thead style="color: red">

                      <tr>
                            <td class="heading">Charge</td>
                            <td class="heading">Cost Before Discount</td>
                            <td class="heading">After Plan Discount</td>
                            <td class="heading">After Booking Discount</td>


                     </tr> 
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${payouts}" var="payout" varStatus="row">
                        <tr>
                             <td >Base Cost</td> 
                             <c:set var="basecost" value="payout.baseCost.costBeforeDiscount" />
                            <td><fmt:formatNumber pattern="########.####"   
          value="${payout.baseCost.costBeforeDiscount}"/></td>
                             <c:set var="basecost" value="payout.baseCost.afterPlanDiscount" />
                             <td><fmt:formatNumber pattern="########.####" 
           value="${payout.baseCost.afterPlanDiscount}"/></td>
                            <c:set var="basecost" value="payout.baseCost.afterBookingDiscount" />
                             <td><fmt:formatNumber pattern="########.####" 
           value="${payout.baseCost.afterBookingDiscount}"/></td>

                        </tr>

                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```