# Why does the double type behave this way?

Tags: java, double, precision

Look at the following code.
Why does the `0.01D` constant make the output so inaccurate?

```
double x = 0D;
while (x < 2D) {
    System.out.println(x);
    x = x + 0.01D;
}
```

> 0.0
>   0.01
>   0.02
>   0.03
>   0.04
>   0.05
>   0.060000000000000005
>   0.07
>   0.08
>   0.09
>   0.09999999999999999
>   0.10999999999999999
>   0.11999999999999998
>   0.12999999999999998
>   0.13999999999999999
>   0.15

Comment: What do you believe the *exact* value of `0.01D` to be? (It's not 0.01...)

Comment: Because floating point numbers are not precise: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: It's actually much worse than this, but part of it is hidden by the way the conversion from `double` to `String` works.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results

Comment: @JonSkeet What is it?

Comment: @Joiner 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn more about the `double` type then, via the linked question...