# Error in floating point calculation in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

Normally, we know that 0.5-0.4 is 0.1. But when I run the code, I get some wrong calculation or the result is not clear to me. Please, may you explain how compiler handle the floating point calculation in Java.

```
System.out.println(0.5-.4);   // my expected output 0.1
System.out.println(0.5f-.4f); //  my expected output 0.1
```

Output:

```
0.09999999999999998
0.099999994
```

Comment: Read this : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html - What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic

Comment: Why was that other comment deleted? I think it definitely is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results

Comment: read this http://floating-point-gui.de/ and then the above oracle paper