# java getting unexpected result when dividing doubles

Tags: java

okay, now I do understand why

```
double paymentSum;
double a = ((paymentSum/100.0)-1.54);
```

returns `a = 0.45999999999999996`
and not  `a=0.46`

here my question would be how to make the result `a=0.46` from the existing result

also `paymentSum` is an input made my user, let's say `paymentSum=200`

Comment: Also check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results

Comment: When you use decimals, you need to consider appropriate rounding.  You can either use BigDecimal which can help you or you need to round the result e.g. when you print it.

Comment: I haven't covered BigDecimal part of java yet. Perks of being new programmer I guess. But I tried learning BigDecimal from other answers here on my own and I have no idea what I just read about BigDecimal. Will have to wait for my professor.

Comment: You can round when printing, but using "floating point" numbers (like `double`) is virtually always a huge mistake when dealing with things like money.