# How to find new coordinates from translation rotation

Tags: java, math, formula

I have one coordinate and want to get a new coordinate after rotation like image below. Can anyone give me a simple formula ?

[image]

EDIT : after using eol formula...

[image: Debug]

there's a very small miss "6.1232338E-15".

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic here. You can look this up in any math textbook.

Comment: if this so simple like that, can u post your math textbook formula here..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use a rotation matrix (taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

```
float newX = x*Math.cos(angleRad) - y*Math.sin(angleRad);
float newY = x*Math.sin(angleRad) - y*Math.cos(angleRad);
```

One thing to mention is that you need to make sure that the angle is in radians, so you may need to perform this conversion:

```
float angleRad = angle*Math.PI/180;
```

Comment: I use your formula but there very small miss in calculation. i know it will ignore in render but you know why?

Comment: @Mardi This might be due to rounding errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results