# Float.valueOf - on Android studio

Tags: android, string, runtime-error

I put code

```
  float _fNum = Float.valueOf("5093.7342");
```

after that `_fNum` value goes `5093.7344`

The result of `Float.valuesOf` goes wrong what I think.

How can I fix it or How can I make it using another method ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results

Comment: What happens if you use double instead of float?