# Moving from Groovy to Java

Tags: java, grails, groovy

In my **grails** project I'm moving all calculations to java classes.

[Here is the link to source code (i've saved it in Google Docs).](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1YOVoSY2FHJALJlSILmYUjkiwr8P1xn4w09CjuXZLsjQ&hl=en&authkey=COrgu8cC)

Main purpose is to format current time into string(in two languages). Examples:

```
1 day 2 hours 3 seconds
1 день 2 часа 3 секунды
```

But i have one method:

```
 private static boolean endsWith(final long num, final long part) {
    if (num / 10 < 1) {
      return num == part;
    } else {
      float val1 = (num - part) / 10;
      float val2 = (float) Math.floor(val1);

      return val1 == val2;
    }
  }
```

It checks if 'num' ends with 'part'.
Examples:

```
assert endsWith(128, 1) == false
assert endsWith(1, 1) == true
assert endsWith(34, 4) == true
```

**P.S.** num - is standard long (java.lang.Long) value and part - is greater than 0 and less or equals than 9 (1..9).

But this code works fine only in **groovy** classes.

In **java** class i got those results:

```
endsWith(7, 7) == true
endsWith(23, 3) == false
endsWith(23, 1) == true
```

As i can see from **gant** log - all code are compiled by **groovyc**.

**P.S.2** I'l compile this code with **groovyc** and **javac** to compare results. Because if i haven't make any mistake it could be a bug in **groovyc**. But this is my mistake i hope :)

Comment: facepalm...
i've totally forgot about '%' operator...
and this person has implemented linear congruential generator just few month ago... hard to believe... thx guys!

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, why move from Groovy to Java, performance?

Comment: Yep, @Don, you are right. Groovy has no primitive values at all - it automatically boxes double into Double, long into Long, etc. so you are losing in performance because of type boxing\unboxing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you using floating point arithmetic at all? Why not just:

```
private static boolean endsWith(final long num, final long part) {
  return (num % 10) == part;
}
```

? If it needs to work for negative numbers you'll need to take the absolute value before the mod, but otherwise that should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

You should never compare floating point values with `==` due to the limited precision.

In fact in this case it doesn't look like you need to go to floating point operation at all. You can use `%` to get the remainder of a number and get the last few digits this way.

Here are some examples (note the sign with negative dividend)

```
123 % 10 == 3
4567 % 100 == 67
-9876 % 10 == -6
```

#### References

- [JLS 15.17.3 Remainder Operator %](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.17.3)

#### Related questions

- [What’s wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)

---

#### `String` operation alternative

Another option is that if performance isn't terribly important, the easiest solution is probably to just convert to `String` and use [`String.endsWith`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29). In this way you also don't have the complication with negative numbers.

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(-9876).endsWith(String.valueOf(76)));
// prints "true"
```

Comment: See also Java Puzzlers, 3.1. Floating-point arithmetic is inexact; Avoid testing floating-point values for equality; Prefer double to float;

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but I'm not comfortable with your conversions to float...

Couldn't you just use return(num % 10) == part?