# Why use Float.floatToIntBits() in Java float comparisons?

Tags: java, vector, floating-point, box2d

In JBox2d, there exists the following code for `Vec2.equals()`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) { //automatically generated by Eclipse
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Vec2 other = (Vec2) obj;
    if (Float.floatToIntBits(x) != Float.floatToIntBits(other.x))
        return false;
    if (Float.floatToIntBits(y) != Float.floatToIntBits(other.y))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I am wondering what purpose the float<->int bit conversions functions serve, here. Does this provide a way to get around Java's float comparison inaccuracy problem (if such is even possible)? Or is it something else altogether? I am wondering if it is an alternative to the epsilon approach:

```
if (Math.abs(floatVal1 - floatVal2) < epsilon)
```

PS. for the sake of completeness and interest, here is `Vec2.hashCode()`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() { //automatically generated by Eclipse
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(x);
    result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(y);
    return result;
}
```

FYI, I can see perfectly why the conversion functions are used in hashCode() -- hash IDs must be integers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The explanation can be found in [Joshua Bloch's Effective Java](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC&dq=effective+java&pg=PP1&ots=UZMZ2siN25&sig=kR0n73DHJOn-D77qGj0wOxAxiZw&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=1&ct=result#v=onepage&q=float.floattointbits&f=false): `float` and `Float` need special treatment because of the existence of `-0.0`, `NaN`, positive infinity, and negative infinity.  That's why the Sun JVM's `Float.equals()` looks like this (6u21):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    return (obj instanceof Float)
           && (floatToIntBits(((Float)obj).value) == floatToIntBits(value));
}
```

So, no, `Math.abs()` with an epsilon is not a good alternative.  From the Javadoc:

> If f1 and f2 both represent Float.NaN,
>   then the equals method returns true,
>   even though Float.NaN==Float.NaN has
>   the value false.  If f1 represents
>   +0.0f while f2 represents -0.0f, or vice versa, the equal test has the
>   value false, even though 0.0f==-0.0f
>   has the value true.

That's why Eclipse's autogenerated code does that for you.

Comment: In other words, this is completely superior to the epsilon approach? I can't believe my luck, if so.

Comment: Well, if you can guarantee that you will not get any `NaNs` or `-0.0` or infinities, then using `Math.abs() < epsilon` might be faster.  Maybe.

Comment: I see from comments below that I was mistaking what this does. It solves problems centred around the special float values; it does not deal with float inaccuracy -- as you initially stated in your answer. So ignore my last question.

Comment: Math.abs() < epsilon MIGHT be faster, but epsilon should(!!) change as your values change. See here for an explanation: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/ Therefore, unless you implement your own function to calculate a good epsilon, you might as well just use equals() since it will always give you the correct answer (to the available precision of your system, and with the exception of -0.0f to 0.0f).

Answer (score 10):

Double.Nan (Not-a-number) is a special value when it comes to comparison:

```
System.out.println(Float.NaN == Float.NaN);
System.out.println(Float.floatToIntBits(Float.NaN) == Float.floatToIntBits(Float.NaN));
```

This prints:

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not know 100%, but most probably they are trying to get around the NaN != NaN problem. If your float happens to be NaN you cannot compare to anything as the result is always false. Comparing the intBits will give you NaN == NaN.