# Compare decimals in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form input to get a number (it is a price). It can be a decimal like 102,5. I have to compare it with an other decimal for exemple 102,6. 
How can handle this ? I don't want to use round() cause i get to compare exactly.

Answer (score 8):

You could compare the [absolute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) (i.e., numerical) difference to an "epsilon" (your "tolerance" <sup>1</sup>):

```
$epsilon = 0.01;
$diff = abs(102.5 - 102.6); // .1
if ($diff <= $epsilon) {
    // The numbers are equal
} else {
    // The numbers are not equal enough!
}
```

And, a little reading: "*[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)*" and "*[Comparing floating point numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm)*".

Also, you may find the follow SO questions (and answers!) interesting:

- [Most effective way for float and double comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)
- [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)

---

<sup>1</sup> That's right: *You* get to decide what makes the two numbers equal. It could be `0.1` (making `1.1` equal to `1.0`), `0.01` (`1.02` ~ `1.03`) etc.

Comment: @Mamadou Are your numbers valid? What does `var_dump()` print?

Answer (score 4):

Don't store prices as floats, use integers (store cents, not dollars).

Comment: Good point. Didn't notice the "it is a price" part in the question :)

Comment: Definitely makes more sense in terms of computing prices.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it decimal out of this format

```
$kinda_decimal = "102,5";
$kinda_decimal = floatval(str_replace(",",".",$kinda_decimal));
```

and compare it

Comment: okay ! the probleme is now when i choose the ( point ) it is not taken as a decimal coma ! I hope you understand ( am french))