# Can we use .contains(BigDecimal.ZERO) when reading a list in JAVA?

Tags: java, contains, bigdecimal

Can we use .contains(BigDecimal.ZERO) when reading a list in JAVA ??

I am trying:

```
    if (selectPriceList.contains(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

But it always returns false.

This seems to work but does it need correction?

```
    BigDecimal zeroDollarValue = new BigDecimal("0.0000");
    if (selectPriceList.contains(zeroDollarValue)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: For the record, you can do a simple `return selectPriceList.contains(zeroDollarValue);`, or, alternately, `return selectPriceList.contains(new BigDecimal("0.0000");`.

Comment: Well... _does_ your list contain `BigDecimal.ZERO`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866514/why-bigdecimal5-50-not-equals-to-bigdecimal5-5-and-how-to-work-around-th

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem occurs because the `scale`, the number of digits to the right of the decimal point, of `BigDecimal.ZERO` is set to 0, while the `scale` of `zeroDollarValue` is 4.

The equals method of `BigDecimal` compares both the scale and the value - if either are different, it returns false.

You can probably use

```
return selectPriceList.contains(BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(4));
```

Assuming that all of your prices go out to four decimal places. If not, you might have to use

```
for(BigDecimal bd : selectPriceList) {
    if(bd.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

For more information, see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: In other words, `BigDecimal.ZERO` is not equal to `new BigDecimal("0.0000")`. That's a known pitfall of `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if(bd.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0)`?