# AssertJ: how to assert BigDecimals using compareTo together with extracting()

Tags: java, assertj

I am using AssertJ `extracting()` method with Java8 lambdas and mapping some fields to BigDecimal, then asserting the resulting array. But I need to compare BigDecimal using `compareTo()` and not with `equals()` (because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102083/why-is-bigdecimal-equals-specified-to-compare-both-value-and-scale-individually)). How can I do that?

Example:

```
Actual actual = performTest();

Assertions.assertThat(actual)
  .extracting(
    Actual::getName,   // returns String
    Actual::getValue  // returns BigDecimal
  )
  .containsExactly(
    "abc",                 // ok, String equals comparison
    new BigDecimal("1.1")  // NOT OK, equals comparison, but I need compareTo comparison
  );
```

Edit: I am looking for a fluent way to do this, because of course I can split this into multiple different Asserts and compare it that way, or put everything in one giant `Condition`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [BigDecimalComparator](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/util/BigDecimalComparator.html) like :

```
Actual actual = performTest();
Assertions.assertThat(actual)
.extracting(
  Actual::getName,   // returns String
  Actual::getValue  // returns BigDecimal
)
.usingComparatorForType(BigDecimalComparator.BIG_DECIMAL_COMPARATOR, BigDecimal.class)
.containsExactly("abc",  new BigDecimal("1.1"));
```

Comment: Nice! I think this has been an addition since the question was originally asked.

Comment: This is perfect. However, when using it, pay attention to actually create a new `BigDecimal` like in the example. I was using `BigDecimal.TEN` and it wasn't working, but when creating one from a string value, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `matches` if it's a one time assertion:

```
assertThat(actual).matches(a -> a.getName().equals("abc") && p.getValue().compareTo(new BigDecimal("1.1")) == 0);
```

If you plan to reuse the assertion, I would create a condition as suggested by @fabienbk.

Comment: Thanks! Because it's actually 1 String and 3 BigDecimals, and it's a one time assertion, I just went for 4 asserts each as their own statement.

Answer (score 0):

If @assylias's solution doesn't work, you can always use a custom Condition.

```
 assertThat(new BigDecimal("1.1")).has(new Condition<BigDecimal>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(BigDecimal s) {
            return s.compareTo(new BigDecimal("1.1")) == 0;
        }
 });
```

Wrap it in a functional interface for a nicer syntax.

**Edit: Using the tuple extractor in your example:**

```
    assertThat(foo).extracting("name", "value").has(new Condition<Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object[] value) {
            return new BigDecimal("1.1").compareTo(value[1]);
        }
    });
```

**Without tuple extractor:**

```
Assertions.assertThat(actual).has(actualValue("abc", new BigDecimal("1.1")));

// Hide this somewhere and import static :)

public static Condition<Actual> actualValue(String expectedName, BigDecimal expectedValue) {
    return new Condition<Actual>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Actual value) {
            return expectedName.equals(value.getName()) && value.getValue().compareTo(expectedValue) == 0;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't have a single `BigDecimal` to compare, but the `extracting` part generates something like an Array or Tuple of `(String, BigDecimal)`. How would I write a different `has()` for the String (or just use normal equals here) and for the`BigDecimal`?

Comment: In that case, simply change the generic parameter from Condition<String> to  Condition<Object[]>. And changes the matches method to take an Object[] as parameter, only using the second item of the array in the compartor. Since it's becoming a bit ugly, you could create an adhoc class for that, so that your test stays a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That does not compile, I have to cast `value[1]` to BigDecimal. It is getting uglier and uglier ;)

Comment: Yeah. I was bored, so i wrote it the cleanest i could, without extractors. Enjoy or ignore :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort :)