# Why is my BigDecimal 0.0000 not equal to BigDecimal.ZERO?

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

I've got the following expression in Android Java:

```
myVar + " == 0 ? " + BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(myVar)
```

which outputs the following:

```
0.0000 == 0 ? false
```

Where `myVar` is declared as:

```
public BigDecimal myVar;
```

And assigned successfully with [`Gson`](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/), from served JSON data (I inspected this to verify the JSON was good). 
**Why does `0.0000` as a `BigDecimal` not equal `BigDecimal.ZERO`?**

Comment: But please post the code that initializes/sets the value for `myVar`.

Comment: `myVar` is assigned from our custom JSON deserializer. "All relevant code" will end up being thousands of lines that you wouldn't want to read even if I was allowed to disclose it.  Long story short: it is successfully converted from a JSON `0.0000` to an Android Java `BigDecimal` `0.0000`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866514/why-bigdecimal5-50-not-equals-to-bigdecimal5-5-and-how-to-work-around-th

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Returns true if x is a BigDecimal instance and if this instance is equal to this big decimal. Two big decimals are equal if their unscaled value and their scale is equal. For example, 1.0 (10*10<sup>-1</sup>) is not equal to 1.00 (100*10<sup>-2</sup>). Similarly, zero instances are not equal if their scale differs.

Why did they decide this?  Probably because its easier to implement.  Is it a good decision?  I don't think so, but it is what it is.  Use another library if you don't like it.

Comment: This makes me want to extend `BigDecimal` and add methods like `equalsIgnoreScale` 

Answer (score 4):

One solution given in [an answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3866544/541796) is to use `compareTo`. So, you could change your code to

```
myVar + " == 0 ? " + (BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(myVar) == 0)
```