# Comparator with double type

Tags: java, casting, double, comparator

I have written the following code:

```
public class NewClass2 implements Comparator<Point>
{
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return (int)(p1.getY() - p2.getY());
    }
}
```

If I let's say have two double numbers, `3.2 - 3.1`, the difference should be `0.1`. When I cast the number to an int, however, the difference ends up as `0`, which is not correct.

I therefore need `compare()` to return a double, not an int. The problem is, my `getX` field is a double. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You don't need to return `double`.

The `Comparator` interface is used to establish an ordering for the elements being compared. Having fields that use `double` is irrelevant to this ordering.

<strike>Your code is fine.</strike>

Sorry, I was wrong, reading the question again, this is what you need:

```
public class NewClass2 implements Comparator<Point> {
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
        if (p1.getY() < p2.getY()) return -1;
        if (p1.getY() > p2.getY()) return 1;
        return 0;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think this will fail with `NaN` and `*_INFINITY`

Answer (score 141):

I suggest you use the builtin method Double.compare(). If you need a range for double values to be equal you can use chcek for that first.

```
return Double.compare(p1.getY(), p2.gety());
```

or

```
if(Math.abs(p1.getY()-p2.getY()) < ERR) return 0;    
return Double.compare(p1.getY(), p2.gety());
```

The problem with using < and > is that NaN will return false in both cases resulting in a possibly inconsistent handling. e.g. NaN is defined as not being equal to anything, even itself however in @suihock's and @Martinho's solutions, if either value is NaN the method will return 0 everytime, implying that NaN is equal to everything.

Comment: Java 7 added compare() for `Long` and `Integer` consistency.

Comment: Here is a [link to the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Double.java#lnmr-999) of `Double.compare()` to see how it handles `NaN`.

Comment: You could probably also use `Math.signum` if you wanted slightly different behavior on NaNs.

Answer (score 21):

Since Java 1.8 you can also use

```
Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> p.getY())
```

Answer (score 10):

The method [`compare`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) should return an `int`. It is a number that is either:

- *Less* than zero, if the first value is *less* than the second;
- *Equal* to zero, if the two values are *equal*;
- *Greater* than zero, if the first value is *greater* than the second;

You don't *need* to return a `double`. You *must* return an `int` to implement the `Comparator` interface. You just have to return the correct `int`, according to the rules I outlined above.

You can't simply cast from int, as, like you said, a difference of 0.1 will result in 0. You can simply do this:

```
public int compare(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    double delta= p1.getY() - p2.getY();
    if(delta > 0) return 1;
    if(delta < 0) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

But since comparison of floating-point values is always troublesome, you should compare within a certain range (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)), something like this:

```
public int compare(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    double delta = p1.getY() - p2.getY();
    if(delta > 0.00001) return 1;
    if(delta < -0.00001) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for complete answer ! I get the whole ! I never forget such a this way

Answer (score 7):

I just want to expand on Peter Lawrey answer on JDK 8, if you do it like this:

```
public class NewClass2 implements Comparator<Point> {
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return Double.compare(p1.getY(), p2.gety());
    }    
}
```

You could define this comparator using a lambda expression pretty easily

```
(Point p1,Point p2) -> Double.compare(p1.getY(), p2.gety())
```

Better yet, you could use a member reference like this:

```
Double::compare
```

Comment: I like the use of the lambda in this answer, its a very good suggestion. I dont understand how you could use a member reference though?  Could you provide an example? thanks

Answer (score 6):

It is so convinent in Java 8, choose anyone just as you wish:

```
Comparator<someClass> cp = (a, b) ->  Double.compare(a.getScore(), b.getScore());

Comparator<someClass> cp = Comparator.comparing(someClass::getScore);

Comparator<someClass> cp = Comparator.comparingDouble(someClass::getScore);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int compare(Double first, Double second) {
    if (Math.abs(first - second) < 1E-6) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return Double.compare(first, second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Double.compare(/**double value 1*/, /**double value 2*/);` with a new Comparator for your model class double value.

```
public static List<MyModel> sortByDouble(List<MyModel> modelList) {
        Collections.sort(modelList, new Comparator<MyModel>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MyModels1, MyModels2) {
                double s1Distance = Double.parseDouble(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s1.distance) ? s1.distance : "0");
                double s2Distance = Double.parseDouble(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s2.distance) ? s2.distance : "0");
                return Double.compare(s1Distance, s2Distance);
            }
        });
        return modelList;
    }
```

Comment: Note that you can revert sort order by using Double.compare(d2, d1) as opposed to Double.compare(d1, d2). Obvious but still.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could multiply those double values by an appropriate factor before converting into integer, for eg. in your case since its only one decimal place so 10 would be a good factor;

```
return (int)(p1.getY()*10 - p2.getY()*10);
```

Comment: This answer only works in certain circumstances. I.e. when multiplying by 10 will result in the double values becoming a whole number.

Comment: @robjwilkins: Could you please clarify that in which case this method of choosing an appropriate factor wouldn't work?

Comment: It doesnt work in the case where getY returns a number which cannot be multiplied by 10 to get an integer. For example if getY returns 3.2111 then this solution will not work.  Since getY returns a double, it is entirely feasible for it to return 3.2111.  This solution is therefore very limited, and there are much better alternatives.

Comment: @robjwilkins In the case you mentioned the 'appropriate factor' would be 10000 and not 10. Agreed that simplicity comes with limitations and tradeoffs, therefore the user decides the most feasible approach according to the needs of his/her use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Double min  = Arrays.stream(myArray).min(Double::compare).get();
```