# Java CompareTO with double Values

Tags: java

I need to be able to rearrange a group of people from their overall fitness score. I am able to do a compareTO method with ints but as soon as its with doubles I get errors flying up everywhere.

```
public double compareTo(FitnessScore o){
    return (this.overall-o.overall);
}
```

It needs to be a double because there are scores like:

```
68.5 68.4 60.1 60.3
```

So casting them to an int would make it redundant. When I did have it as an int to see if it would work. I tried the following. (subjects being the array that I initialized to hold all the different instances of people)

```
Arrays.sort(subjects);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerExceptione
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242023/comparator-with-double-type

Comment: Use ```Double.compare``` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29

Comment: Can you provide more of your code?

Arrays.sort(subjects)
Is subjects an array? Has it been initialised?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `compareTo` must alaways return an `int` value.

**-1** for placing it before in Collection
**0** indicates same value already exists in Collection
**+1** for placing it afterwards in Collection

If `overall` is of type `Double`, use this:

```
public int compareTo(FitnessScore o){
    return this.overall.compareTo(o.overall));
}
```

If `overall` is of type `double`, use this:

```
public int compareTo(FitnessScore o){
    if(this.overall<o.overall)
          return -1;
    else if(o.overall<this.overall)
          return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

And for your `NullPointerException`, check that your `subjects` is not null.

Comment: But your method returns a double. And not, it's not - 1 or +1. It's negative, zero, or positive.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for poiting out, forgot to correct it

Comment: @Aditya I'm still not sure about the NullPointerException. I have put in a try and catch that just ignores and then processes the information anyway. All my numbers are there so is there a way of combating it or is something that I should just leave?

Comment: @Softey Please post some more code and also show your error log.

Comment: @Aditya I've sorted it. Rogue null made it's way in. My old code works now. Thank you for the answer anyway

Answer (score 7):

You are breaking the signature of compareTo method. 
    It should look like below,

```
public int compareTo(FitnessScore o){
    return Double.compare(this.overall-o.overall);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the Comparator interface. Dont worry about your values. Even if the compare method is returning an int. This int is not one of your values.

Also check this out.
[Comparator with double type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242023/comparator-with-double-type)

Answer (score 0):

Your `compareTo()` method receives a `FitnessScore` object. However, it does not test for null case.

When `o` is `null`, your method will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
Double obj1 = this.overall;
Double obj2 = o.overall;

int retval =  obj1.compareTo(obj2);
```

//then do your normal if else block.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface:

```
class OFSComparator implements Comparator<Member> {
   public int compare(Member m1, Member m2) {
      return (m1.ofs.compareTo(m2.ofs));
   }
}
```

Each Member should have a field for overall fitness score

```
Double ofs;
```

And if you later want to sort members based on their overall fitness score, you can use [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
Arrays.sort(members, new OFSComparator());
```