# How to compare two lists of double values using lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, comparison

Let's start with the following lists :

```
List<Double> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
firstList.add(2.0);
firstList.add(3.0);
List<Double> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
secondList .add(2.0000000001);
secondList .add(2.99999999994);
```

I know I can compare each element one by one using brute force. Of course, I already checked that both lists have the same number of elements.

```
boolean isEqual = true;
for (int i = 0; i < firstList.size(); i++) {
  isEqual &= Math.abs(firstList.get(i) - secondList.get(i)) < 1.0e-6;
}
return isEqual;
```

My question : is there a way to compare these two lists of double values using lambda expressions? It seems to be easy with any other type of objects, but not with doubles. I need to check if the two lists are numerically equal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that lambdas are necessary?  What you have there works absolutely fine.

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242023/comparator-with-double-type

Comment: @Joe C I know this works fine. I was curious to see how to do teh same using lambdas.

Comment: @clinomaniac Yes, order is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the statement:

> Of course, I already checked that both lists have the same number of
>   elements.

Then you can accomplish the same result with `IntStream.range` along with `allMatch` like so:

```
boolean isEqual =  firstList.isEmpty() || 
         IntStream.range(0, firstList.size())
           .allMatch(i -> Math.abs(firstList.get(i) - secondList.get(i)) < 1.0e-6);
```

Another solution using `reduce`:

```
BiPredicate<Double, Double> biPredicate = (e, a) -> Math.abs(e - a) < 1.0e-6;
boolean isEqual = 
         IntStream.range(0, firstList.size())
                  .boxed()
                  .reduce(Boolean.TRUE,
                    (accumulator, i) -> Boolean.logicalAnd(accumulator, biPredicate.test(firstList.get(i), secondList.get(i))),
                    (a, b) -> {
                        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
                    });
```

I've intentionally left the third parameter (the combiner) to `reduce` unimplemented as it will not be called at all. Reason being that this specific overload was designed to be used with a parallel stream, so in order for a combiner to work, a stream must be parallel.

Yet, it's still necessary for us to use this overload in order to accomplish the task at hand.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use combiner field. Can't you use just `T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator);`?

Comment: @MichałZabielski that overload states that the `identity`, as well as the parameters of the `accumulator` _must all, be the same type_. if I was to proceed with that approach the code wouldn't compile. Hence the need for this overload which allows having the `identity` be a different type than the elements in the stream. in this case, `accumulator` is of type `Boolean` and `i` of type `Integer`. This enables me to fold into a boolean result as well as having access to the index.

Comment: @MichałZabielski see the signature of the overload [you've suggested](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) and the overload [I am using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

Comment: Ok, now i see it. In fact you are performing two steps in reduce: comparing `double` from two lists, and then reducing it to one boolean. Nice to know this technique with `combiner` field:)

Comment: I would never use the 2nd approach. It's not only longer, but also *non short-circuiting*. If one pair of elements don't satisfy the condition, why keep on checking until the last one?

Answer (score 2):

In functional languages you can use `zip` function to zip two lists (streams) and then use map or reduce to manipulate merged list using lambdas. Unfortunately Java doesn't have such function out-of-the-box. However, you can use Google  Guava `Streams` to zip two lists and obtain result with lambda (functional style):

```
    BiFunction<Double, Double, Boolean> zippingFunction = (a, b) -> Math.abs(a - b) < 1.0e-6;

    boolean result = Streams.zip(firstList.stream(), secondList.stream(), zippingFunction)
            .reduce(true, Boolean::logicalAnd);
```

Comment: nice!. you can achieve the same thing without an external library, although it may not be as neat. I've provided it in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Create an interface with a compare method that takes two List and returns boolean. Wrap your existing code in a lambda expression.