# How can I check if a value is of type Integer?

Tags: java, integer

I need to check if a value is an integer. I found this: [How to check whether input value is integer or float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727569/how-to-check-whether-input-value-is-integer-or-float), but if I'm not mistaken, the variable there is still of type `double` even though the ***value*** itself is indeed an `integer`.

Comment: How are you getting the input? Is it a String?

Comment: @Code-Guru: I shouldn't have said input at all. Sorry, I meant just "whatever value". I'm editing now.

Comment: Even so, we still need more details. How are you storing this value that you want to check?

Comment: @Code-Guru: Oh, well... *it is sometimes a string, but other times I want to try it with a double*. I didn't know it would make a difference :(

Comment: @Voldemort programs in Java.  This alone answers a lot of questions I had about the Potter books.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If input value can be in  numeric form other than integer , check by

```
if (x == (int)x)
{
   // Number is integer
}
```

If string value is being passed , use `Integer.parseInt(string_var).`
Please ensure error handling using try catch in case conversion fails.

Comment: *ahem* try/catch parseint.

Answer (score 29):

If you have a double/float/floating point number and want to see if it's an integer.

```
public boolean isDoubleInt(double d)
{
    //select a "tolerance range" for being an integer
    double TOLERANCE = 1E-5;
    //do not use (int)d, due to weird floating point conversions!
    return Math.abs(Math.floor(d) - d) < TOLERANCE;
}
```

If you have a string and want to see if it's an integer. Preferably, don't throw out the `Integer.valueOf()` result:

```
public boolean isStringInt(String s)
{
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you want to see if something is an Integer object (and hence wraps an `int`):

```
public boolean isObjectInteger(Object o)
{
    return o instanceof Integer;
}
```

Comment: Using == to compare doubles (as in your `isDoubleInt()` method) is dangerous because of loss of precision. Instead, you should do something like `Math.floor(d) - d < DELTA;` where `DELTA` is set to some very small value.

Comment: Your code is wrong. It should be `< TOLERANCE` not `> TOLERANCE`.

Comment: @andresp Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: You are welcome. You are still missing a semi-colon after 1E-5, but that's easily noticed once you try to compile.

Comment: This answer is underrated.  I'm using it to make an educated guess as to whether a double (Apache POI always treats numbers as doubles) was "intended" to be displayed as an integer so I can use Gson (which will look at my object representation, which I want to be Integer) to convert to JSON.

Comment: What will happen if `d = 0.999999`?

Comment: Ultimately you have to choose a cutoff. Chose one that's reasonable, but test it thoroughly. Too large of a cutoff and you'll get false positives, too narrow and you'll get false negatives.

That, or, use `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 23):

```
if (x % 1 == 0)
    // x is an integer
```

Here `x` is a numeric primitive: `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` or `double`

Answer (score 8):

Try maybe this way

```
try{
    double d= Double.valueOf(someString);
    if (d==(int)d){
        System.out.println("integer"+(int)d);
    }else{
        System.out.println("double"+d);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("not number");
}
```

But all numbers outside Integers range (like "-1231231231231231238") will be treated as doubles. If you want to get rid of that problem you can try it this way

```
try {
    double d = Double.valueOf(someString);
    if (someString.matches("\\-?\\d+")){//optional minus and at least one digit
        System.out.println("integer" + d);
    } else {
        System.out.println("double" + d);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("not number");
}
```

Comment: As Code-Guru pointed on on my answer, `d` may look like this: 47.000000001, due to loss of precision. You can never trust a double to be exact. Use range checking to solve this.

Answer (score 8):

You should use the `instanceof` operator to determine if your value is Integer or not;

Object object = your_value;

```
if(object instanceof Integer) {

Integer integer = (Integer) object ;

} else {
 //your value isn't integer
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the function for to check is String is Integer or not ?

```
public static boolean isStringInteger(String number ){
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(number);
    }catch(Exception e ){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can work:

```
int no=0;
try
{
    no=Integer.parseInt(string);
    if(string.contains("."))
    {
        if(string.contains("f"))
        {
            System.out.println("float");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("double");
    }
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("not numeric or string");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a String contains digit character which represent an integer, you can use `Integer.parseInt()`.

To check if a double contains a value which can be an integer, you can use `Math.floor()` or `Math.ceil()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check if it's a number. If so you can use the `Math.Round` method. If the result and the original value are equal then it's an integer.

Answer (score 1):

this is the shortest way I know with negative integers enabled:

```
Object myObject = "-1";

if(Pattern.matches("\\-?\\d+", (CharSequence) myObject);)==true)
{
    System.out.println("It's an integer!");
}
```

And this is the way with negative integers disabled:

```
Object myObject = "1";

if(Pattern.matches("\\d+", (CharSequence) myObject);)==true)
{
    System.out.println("It's an integer!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet of code

```
private static boolean isStringInt(String s){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(s);
    return in.hasNextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus %, the solution is so simple:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter first number");
    Double m = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter second number");
    Double n= scan.nextDouble();

    if(m%n==0) 
    {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Double");
    }


}
}
```