# How to Check Whether a Variable is an Integer or Not

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, logic, division

I'm new to programming in Java and I'm attempting to learn the ropes as I go along. I have ran into a problem, the problem stems with my inability to check whether a variable is an integer or not.

```
int[] values = new int[3];
private Random rand = new Random();
num1 = rand.nextInt(70);
num2 = rand.nextInt(70);
num3 = rand.nextInt(70);

values[1] = num1 + num2

//we are dividing values[1] by num3 in order to produce an integer solution. For example (4 + 3) / 2 will render an integer answer, but (4 + 3) / 15 will not. 
//The (correct) answer is values[2]

values[2] = values[1]/num3

if (num3 > values[1]) {
     //This is done to ensure that we are able to divide by the number to get a solution (although this would break if values[1] was 1).
     num3 = 2
     while (values[2] does not contain an integer value) {
         increase num3 by 1
        work out new value of values[2]
        }    
} else {
    while (values[2] does not contain an integer value) {
         increase num3 by 1
        work out new value of values[2] <--- I'm not sure if this step is necessary
    }
}

System.out.println(values[2]);
```

Comment: if (num == (int)num)
{
   // Number is integer
}

Comment: Where and how `values` is defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a value is of type Integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558206/how-can-i-check-if-a-value-is-of-type-integer)

Comment: This makes no sense. Primitives arrays require a type. They can 'only' hold that type. So if you have an `int[]` all the elements are ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide an integer by another integer you will always have an integer.

You need the modulo (remainder) operation

```
int num1 = 15;
int num2 = 16;
int num3 = 5;

System.out.println("num1/num3 = "+num1/num3);
System.out.println("num2/num3 = "+num2/num3);
System.out.println("num1%num3 = "+num1%num3);
System.out.println("num2%num3 = "+num2%num3);
```

If the modulo is not 0 then the result would not be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
if(value%1 == 0){
  //True if Integer
}
```

E.g. `2.34f % 1` will be `0.34` but `2f % 1 is 0.0`

Answer (score 2):

The following will never happen because the `values` array is of type primitive int. As such checking if `values[2]` is an int is after the fact. `values[]` will `always` contain an int and trying to add an element to the values array that's not of type int will result in an **[ArrayStoreException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.5)** being thrown.

> If the type of the value being assigned is not assignment-compatible (§5.2) with the component type, an ArrayStoreException is thrown.

```
// All three are of type int
num1 = rand.nextInt(70);
num2 = rand.nextInt(70);
num3 = rand.nextInt(70);

// Not possible... 
while (values[2] does not contain an integer value) {
```

When you initialize the values array it will automatically have default the values of `0`.

```
int[] values = new int[3]
System.out.println( Arrays.toString(values) );
> [0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If input value can be in numeric form other than integer , check by

```
if (x == (int)x){
   // Number is integer
}
```

If string value is being passed , use Integer.parseInt(string_var).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(value == (int) value)
```

or a long (64-bit integer)

```
if(value == (long) value)
```

or can be safely represented by a float without a loss of precision

```
if(value == (float) value)
```

If a string value is being passed, use `Integer.parseInt(value)`; which will return an integer if the input passed is the correct integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use instanceof operator to check if the given object is an Integer.

```
if(num instanceof Integer)
    System.out.println("Number is an integer");
```