# Does DateUtil.AddDays accept a variable for the # of days?

Tags: variables, compiler-errors, int, apache-commons, java.util.date

I'm trying to use a variable for the number of days in my call to `DateUtil.addDays`, but it's not working.  Am I missing something simple, or does it just not work?

```
//Example:
x = 10  //this int is the result of some math, and changes frequently
y = Thu Aug 31 00:00:00 MST 2017  //this is the date

z = DateUtil.addDays(y, x)   //This will error.
z = DateUtil.addDays(y, 10)  //This works.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Keep in mind that people cannot help you find the correct solution if they can't see all the relevant details of your problem. For instance :  What is the type of variable `x` ? What is the "error" : compilation ? run-time exception? What is the error message ?

Comment: In general, using a value as function argument `foo(10);` or a variable `int x = 10; foo(x);`will be treated similarly by the Java language, but you have to be careful about which **types** are required in your function, and be aware that some automatic type conversion can happen too. Here, the `addDays` method requires an `int`as second argument. So, is your `x` variable an `int`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I tested x with the answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558206/how-can-i-check-if-a-value-is-of-type-integer and the result came back as int

Comment: Be careful ! The test you linked is to check if the **value is an integer**, not if the **type of the variable is an integer**  ! example : `float x = 2.0; ` will pass your test, the value is the same as the integer 2, but the variable is **not** an `int`, it's a `float`, and any attempt to use this variable in a function asking for an `int` will cause a compilation error !

Comment: You should search your code and check the **declared type of x**.

Comment: If it is a float / double or so, you can try to get an `int`out of it by, for instance, use the `Math.round(x)` function. But to tell you the correct answer, I have to know the type of variable `x` : double / float / string / other...

Comment: Well now don't I feel silly.  I simply converted via "int xyz = x" and now it works.  Thank you very much Mr. Pac0!  :)

Comment: You are welcome. This is a usual mistake to do when learning Java and other "strongly typed languages".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful with your types in Java.

Examples :

```
// suppose variable y contains your date as in your example
int x = 10;                   // value is 10
double w = x;                 // value is same as 10 (or, more precisely, 10.0)

z = DateUtil.addDays(y, x);   // This will compile. 

// This will not compile. AddDays expect an argument of type `int`,
// not a `double`, even if the value inside is mathematically
// the same as the int 10.
 z = DateUtil.addDays(y, w);

// This will compile : the result of Math.round() is of type int
z = DateUtil.addDays(y, Math.round(w));
```