# How to check the input format in java

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal, type-conversion

i need to check whether the number input is in decimal format or in floating point format in java coding.

in simple terms how would this check be possible?

Comment: here is one way to do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/38714547/43848

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether input value is integer or float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727569/how-to-check-whether-input-value-is-integer-or-float)

Comment: what do you mean by decimal format..?

Comment: decimal format - a number that is either positive or negative but is to the base 10. for example 20.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
if(scanner.hasNextDouble())
     //double stuff here
else if (scanner.hasNextFloat())
     //Float stuff here
```

Comment: so how would i write this out in terms of explaining the code?

Comment: What do you  mean by 'explaining the code'? The sample code I provided is pretty self-explanatory I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small method I quickly whipped up that you may find interesting....

```
public static boolean isFloatingPoint(Object number) {
    String type = number.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();
    return type.equals("FLOAT") || type.equals("DOUBLE");
}
```

You can use the same concept to determine any Object passed to your method, perhaps even:

```
public static boolean isJButton(Object component) {
    String type = component.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();
    return type.equals("JBUTTON");
}
```