# Checking float values in android with ifelse

Tags: java, android, floating-point

I am making an android game that needs to check a float x value, if the value is 320 it should be reset to 1, and if it is not, it should be increased by 15. This is the code that I am using, but however, it is not working:

```
if (x == 320) {
    x = 1;
    Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
    parachuters.add(p);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "x=" + x + " y=" + y, 15).show();
}
else {
    x = x + 15;
    Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
    parachuters.add(p);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "x=" + x + " y=" + y, 15).show();
}
```

Comment: Do some logging and provide examples - what's the value at each moment - before the first IF, in each branch, and in the end. What are your expectations and what's the actual value.

Comment: [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1088216/651140)

Comment: try comparing as: `if (x == 320.0)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us what is not working? With floats try and use the F extension to identify its a float (for example x == 320.0f).

I have a feeling you want to know if the X position is greater than or equal to 320, in which case you need to use the following:

```
            if (x >= 320) {
                x = 1;
                Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
                parachuters.add(p);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "x=" + x + " y=" + y, 15).show();
            }
            else {
                x += 15;
                Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
                parachuters.add(p);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "x=" + x + " y=" + y, 15).show();
            }
```

Also, I would advise you print out to the Logs rather than creating Toasts every time.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. But i want to know if x is less than or equal to 320. Thanks for the tips for the toasts:-) It doesn't react when the value is equal and above 320, it just keeps on going without resetting to 1

Comment: More than likely, the 'x' value is never 320 because of the increment you are using :) If you divide 320 by 15, you get a remainder, which means you will never hit that condition. Also, if 320 is supposed to be your screen width, remember that not all phones are of the same size!

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare floating point values in this way. Instead of `x == 320.0`, they should be compared like this:

```
if (Math.abs(x - 320.0) < EPS) {}
```

where `EPS` is a small value like `1e-6` or something small like that.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only code that changes the value of x, then the problem is that x will never be 320.  If x starts at 1 and you increment it by 15 each time, then x will eventually become 316, and then 331.

If x starts as 0, then it will become 315 and then 330.

Perhaps changing your `if` statement to test `x >= 320` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use debugger and check what is the value of each variable at a time. It may help to find out the which value assigned to a variable is not working in a correct way.