# Keeping a SortedSet of objects based on a property

Tags: java, sorting, set, sortedset

I have an object, `Test`, that has two properties, `double x` and `double y`. I want to add these objects to a `SortedSet`, keeping the set sorted in ASC order on x of `Test`. If two instances of `Test` have the same x values, I want them to be sorted within the set by their y values.

I thought the following would do the trick:

```
private SortedSet<Test> tests = new TreeSet<Test>(new Comparator<Test>() {

@Override
public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
    if (o1.getXpos() < o2.getXpos()) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (o1.getXpos() > o2.getXpos()) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (o1.getXpos() == o2.getXpos()) {
        if (o1.getYpos() < o2.getYpos()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o1.getYpos() > o2.getYpos()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o1.getYpos() == o2.getYpos()) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
});
```

Instead this orders the actual x and y values; i.e.

> testA: x=200, y=200,
>
> testB: x=200, y=400

After inserting into `tests`:

> testA: x=200, y=200,
>
> testB: x=400, y=200

Instead of the instances within `tests`.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html may simplify your comparison logic.

Comment: Can you post the code for `Test.equals`? BTW, the test `if (o1.getXpos() == o2.getXpos())` is implied because the two `x` values are neither `<` nor `>`, assuming they're real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your comparator is correct.  you've got bigger problems, though, if adding your Test objects to the set changes their member variables, e.g. "testB: x=400, y=200" -> "testB: x=200, y=400".  I would guess your problem lies in code you have not included (maybe a botched constructor?).

Comment: could very well be the case; looking at some code I didn't write now.

Comment: you're correct; the constructor for `Test` takes ypos,xpos.. not xpos,ypos.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with more than two elements?  More than once I've simply sorted things backwards without realizing it until later.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that comparing the `double`s for exact equality using `==` is potentially the issue.  See [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)