# Input string was not in a correct format and the line

Tags: c#

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Double d;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text))
        {
            d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            var c = d / 1;

            if (c == 0.75)
            {


                string myString = c.ToString();


            }
            else if (c == 0.25)
            {  }
            else if (c == 0.50) {  }
            else if (c == 0.00) { }
            else { MessageBox.Show("you can't enter this"); }
        }
    }
```

ok so i fixed that error but every time i enter a number the messagebox shows you cant enter this , even though d=5.0/1 = 0 and d=0.75/1 = 0.75 and i don't know why
any help would be appreciated

Comment: What value you enter in texbox4 when it give you an error, you can use Int32.TryParse() to avoid errors

Comment: when im trying to enter .75 , when i used your Int32.TryParse() code it gave me an error :  No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments

Comment: try like `int num = 0;Int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out num) `

Comment: `.75` is not an integer. it is `double`

Comment: then i need to convert my textbox4 value to double , how to do that ?

Comment: In your VS type `Convert.` and see what methods are there.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Be aware that `double`s are not supposed to be compared using `==` (`(c == .75)`).

Comment: then how can i compare between 0.75 and the input im entering in textbox4 ?

Comment: It is about Java, but the principle is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java
(Well, if you really want to be absolutely precise, you could write code to normalize your double-as-string and compare against "0.75"-string. But I doubt you really want it.)

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin the cat:

```
string s = "3"; // you should have your text here
int i ;

// Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'
// i=s; 

//The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('int' is a non-nullable value type)
//i = s as int; 

// OK
i = Convert.ToInt32(s);

// Ok, but if s is not number, will throw an exception
i = Int32.Parse(s)

// OK, try_parse will be true, and i will hold the value
// or try_parse will be false, and i will not be set
bool try_parse = Int32.TryParse(s, out i);
```

while i was writting this, i see the conversation continues ... double has a try parse method as well:

```
var s = "0.45";
double d;
bool b = Double.TryParse(s, out d);
```

Answer (score 0):

> then i need to convert my textbox4 value to double , how to do that ?

You can [`Convert.ToDouble(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx) method which is explicitly call [`Double.Parse(string, CurrentCulture)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx). Here how this method [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs);

```
public static double ToDouble(String value)
{
      if (value == null)
          return 0;
      return Double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

And this `Double.Parse(string, CurrentCulture)` [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs) as;

```
public static double Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
{
     return Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float| NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
                     NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}
```

[`NumberStyles.Float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) is a composite style which is include `AllowDecimalPoint` style. You didn't tell us what is your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) exactly but if your current thread culture's [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) is dot (`.`) you can use this method.

If it is not, you can use directly [`Double.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx) which format has a dot (`.`) as a decimal separator like [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "5.0"; // or 5.0 or .75 or 23 or ..
string err = "input is not a number!";

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
{
MessageBox.Show(err);

return;
}

Double d;

// using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture - assuming that decimal point will always be "."
if (!Double.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{
MessageBox.Show(err);

return;
}

// at this point there is a "d" variable 100% a number, do whatever you want with it
// AND BTW 5.0/1 = 5.0, not 0 !!

MessageBox.Show(d.ToString());

var c = d / 1; //WHY is this there? Every number (even negative number) divide by 1 is the same  number, not matter if it is 4 or 100565.432345 or googol ;)

string myString = String.Empty;

if (c == 0.75)
myString = c.ToString();
else if (c == .25)
myString = c.ToString();
else if (c == .5)
myString = c.ToString();

// etc, etc.. don't know your use case
```

Answer (score -3):

That's because you are trying to convert a string to a integer and you get an exception.
`Convert` class does not handle exceptions. You should use `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`, because `TryParse` won't crush your program and you can act accordingly to format errors. Use `Convert` only when you are 100% sure the input can be converted

Something like

```
if(int.TryParse(textBox4.Text,out d))
{
    //continue with your code
}
else
{
    //print something like 'that was not a number'
}
```

Edit: I just checked you want to compare to `.75`, so it would be like this

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        double d;
        double yourValue = 0.75d; // or whatever value you want
        if(Double.TryParse(textBox4.Text,out d))
            if(d == yourValue)
                MessageBox.Show(d.ToString);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Not a number"); // or do nothing, whatever you want 


}
```

Comment: That isn't going to fix the fundamental problem of *why* his input can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: when i used your Int.TryParse() code it gave me an error : No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments

Comment: how can i compare between 0.75 and the input im entering in textbox4 ? because i cant compare between double using == ((c == .75)).

Comment: you can compare them, but it is not 100% accurate when comparing floating numbers

Comment: That's because what you enter is not any of the 4 values you are accepting.