# If Statement for Floats?

Tags: c#

How do I make If statements using floats? The code I have is as follows:

```
{float p1 = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
if (p1 == ""){MessageBox.Show("Home");}}
```

The p1 if statement on the second line does not work. How do I make a proper if statement for this?

EDIT: I should explain. The goal is to check for an empty box. I can't use a string command since I want this to interpret numbers.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is the second line supposed to mean? Are you checking for a blank textbox?

Answer (score 4):

`float` values cannot be "empty". If you try parsing an empty string into a `float`, you would get a runtime error.

You need to check the string for being empty *before* parsing, and then parse with a more "conservative" `TryParse` method that does not throw an exception.

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(textBox1.Text)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Home");
}
float p1;
if (!float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out p1)) {
    MessageBox.Show("textBox1 is not a float");
}
```

Note: In general, comparing `float`s for equality with `==` operator is not a good idea, because `float` is not an exact representation. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1088216/335858) discusses the problem in Java, but the issue is relevant in all languages that use floating point representation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to check whether or not it was able to successfully parse a `float` value from `textBox1.Text`, use `TryParse` instead like so:

```
float p1;
if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out p1))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Home");
}
```

If you're simply trying to check for an empty text box, you could do this instead:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    // Now we can try to parse p1 (assuming it's a valid number)
    float p1 = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Home");
}
```

Note that you would also have to handle invalid characters this way (such as letters, symbols, or spaces).