# How to properly compare two Float wrappers in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point

I already know how to compare floats and this is not the question.

When I compare float I cannot just do that:

```
if(flot1 == flot2) {
    // do something
}
```

Indeed I was always taught to do something like this:

```
if(Math.abs(float1 - float2) < epsilon) {
    // do something
}
```

But the question is when I use float wrappers... for example there is something as simple as the method equal():

```
if(floatWrapper1.equals(floatWrapper2)) {
    // do something
}
```

But reading the documentation that this is equivalent to:

```
if(floatWrapper1.floatValue() == floatWrapper2.floatValue()) {
    // do something
}
```

That is the same like the example (2) that is wrong for the purpose of comparison.

Looking in internet I then found some examples like this:

```
if(Float.compare(flotWrapper1, floatWrapper2) == 0) {
    // do something
}
```

But, I was wonder if this is right neither. How should I then compare two float wrappers?

Comment: You can also use `if(Math.abs(float1 - float2) < epsilon)` with Floats...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)

Comment: @Bubletan not exactly: the op seems to assume that it will only work with primitives - I added a comment to say that it would also work with the boxed type.

Comment: @assylias Oh yeah, nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is because of Auto boxing, comparing `Float`s is no different than comparing `float`s. Save for a null pointer check, you can treat them equivalently.