# Search in a column of DataGridView based on user input in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to match user input in `TextBox1` to values of first column in a `DataGridView` and if the value matched first column of a row, then return the value of second column in that row.

For example, I have these 2 rows of data:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 80000f, 1.000f, 1.120f });
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 85000f, 1.044f, 1.158f });
```

If the user enters 80000 into `TextBox1` I want to return 1.000

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean "Index"? do you mean sort by that column?

Comment: Save a dictionary of Col2 -> List<Row>. Could use some wrapping for that specific usage.

Comment: And what is the result for input 85000? is it 1.044?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
var rseult= this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Where(r=>(float)r.Cells[0].Value==float.Parse(textBox1.Text))
                .Select(r=>(float)r.Cells[1].Value)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

The result for 80000 is 1.000
The result for 85000 is 1.044

Comment: It could cause problems to compare floats without epsilon, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values

Comment: @qub1n I think C# `==` operator works fine. I tested `1.00==float.Parse("1.0000000")` and `1f==float.Parse("1.0000000")` and the result was true.

Comment: Yes, that it is, install the provider from Nuget. I entity framework specific setting will appear in web.config.