# Find Cube Root of Number (without using cbrt())

Tags: java, math

My code works perfectly for some floating value such as `125.5`:

```java
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        NewClass ob = new NewClass();
        double n = Input.nextDouble();
        double cbrt = ob.Cbrt(n);
        System.out.println(cbrt);
    }

    public  double GetSquareRoot(double n, double low, double high) {
        double cbrt = (low + high) / 2;
        
        if (cbrt*cbrt*cbrt > n)
            return GetSquareRoot(n, low, cbrt);
        if (cbrt*cbrt*cbrt < n)
            return GetSquareRoot(n, cbrt, high);
        return cbrt;
    }

    public double Cbrt(double n) {
        NewClass ob = new NewClass();
        return ob.GetSquareRoot(n, 0, n);
    }
}
```

It does not give correct answer when input is:

- `0.008`
- or `0.125`
- or `50`
- or `100`

Then I am getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

When input is `125.5` or `125` or `8` it gives the correct solution.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Not really to your question, but `GetSquareRoot` should probably be `getCubicRoot`.

Comment: @Parth Patel : what the error you see?

Comment: I am getting java.lang.StackOverflowError @Jayan

Answer (score 2):

The error is that this line:

```
return ob.GetSquareRoot(n, 0, n);
```

(which is, of course, misnamed) tries to find a solution between 0 and `n`.  However, if 0 < *n* < 1, then *n*<sup>1/3</sup> > *n*, so you will never find a solution in the interval (0, *n*).  You'll need to make a special case of this; for example, if 0 < *n* < 1, you can search the interval (*n*, 1) instead.

Also, using 0 and `n` as the bounds won't work for negative numbers, so if you want to make your method more complete and handle those cases, you'll need special cases for those too (probably different for -1 < *n* < 0 and *n* < -1).

**MORE:**  After seeing your comment about `StackOverflowError`, it's occurred to me that you have an additional problem: that you're expecting an exact result.  When you put in 0.008, the cube root is 0.2.  However, neither 0.008 nor 0.2 can be represented exactly as a floating-point number.  The consequence is that if you let `cbrt` = whatever value is closest to 0.2 that can be represented, then `cbrt*cbrt*cbrt` won't be exactly 0.008.  It can't be exactly 0.008 anyway, since 0.008 can't be represented as a `double`; however, if `n` is whatever value is closest to 0.008, then it's likely that `cbrt*cbrt*cbrt` will not be exactly equal to `n`, due to roundoff errors.  For a calculation like this, it's important that you *not* compare doubles for equality; instead, compare them using an "epsilon" value, or a margin of error.  Thus, after

```
double cbrt = (low + high) / 2;
```

you should have something like

```
if (Math.abs(cbrt*cbrt*cbrt - n) < EPSILON)
    return cbrt;
```

where EPSILON is some small value such as 1E-10.  (I've sometimes seen code where EPSILON is computed to be a relative value, i.e. `abs(n * RELATIVE_EPSILON)`, instead of an absolute value.)

Another way to avoid `StackOverflowError` is to quit when `low` and `high` become really close, because by that point you're not going to gain much more accuracy, and you need to make sure you exit the algorithm even if the value of `cbrt*cbrt*cbrt` is a little bit off.  Something like

```
if (high - low < EPSILON)
    return cbrt;
```

See also [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java).

Comment: if (Math.abs(cbrt*cbrt*cbrt - n) < EPSILON)
       return cbrt;

Comment: It looks like you tried to copy some code from my answer (and didn't use the `*` correctly, which cause special things to happen in comments), but was there a question about it?

Comment: I tried
 
      if (Math.abs(cbrt*cbrt*cbrt - n) < EPSILON)
       return cbrt;

_and_ 

if (high - low < EPSILON)
    return cbrt;

EPSILON == 0.00000001

but I am not getting correct solution. 

Do you know how calculator calculates accurately result? We can use that method to calculate correct solution.

Comment: Did you also make the first change I recommended?  If you're getting an answer instead of `StackOverflowException`, but it's the wrong answer, you may need to reread the first part of my answer.  And I don't know how calculators calculate this.  They may use a Taylor series, or they may compute the log, divide by 3, then compute the exponential, or maybe some other method.  I have no idea.

Comment: I tried it, and I'm getting close to the correct results, although for 0.008 I get something like 0.19999999999996 instead of 0.2, which might be the best you can do.  (The smaller you make EPSILON, the more accuracy you will get, except that if you make it too small, it will no longer be significant and you'll start getting `StackOverflowException` again.)

Answer (score -1):

```
//How about My Solution - Without Recursive

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CubeRoot {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = input.next();
    Boolean negative = false;
    if (str.startsWith("-")) {
        str = str.substring(1);
        negative = true;
    }
    if (str.indexOf(".") > 0) {
        // find the poisition of '.'
        int pPos = str.length() - 1 - str.indexOf(".");
        String plainStr = (str.substring(0, str.indexOf('.')).concat(str.substring(str.indexOf('.') + 1)));
        StringBuffer cStr = new StringBuffer(cubeRoot(plainStr));

        if (cStr.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(plainStr))
            System.out.println("couldn't compute Cube Root for this :(");
        else {
            if (cStr.length() > pPos / 3) // devide 3 times to put the '.'
                cStr.insert(cStr.length() - pPos / 3, ".");
            else {
                int cStrLength = cStr.length();
                for (int i = 0; i <= pPos / 3 - cStrLength; i++)
                    cStr = new StringBuffer("0").append(cStr.toString());
                cStr.insert(cStr.length() - pPos / 3, ".");
            }
            String append = (negative) ? new String("-") : new String("");
            System.out.println(append + cStr.toString());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not a floating num");
    }
}

private static String cubeRoot(String d) {
    Long l = new Long(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (i * i * i == l) {
            return String.valueOf(i);
        }
    }
    return d;

}

}
```

Comment: Do you know what a cube **root** is?  This appears to compute the cube, not the cube root.

Comment: @ajb Corrected !!!!!