# Smallest number in array that is not 0

Tags: java, arrays

trying to find the smallest value in an array that isn't 0 as the array will almost always have empty values, i've got this far but stuck on how to stop it finding the 0's

```
 float smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
for(int x=0; x<priceArr.length;x++) {
    if(smallest > priceArr[x]) {
    smallest = priceArr[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: add `priceArr[x]!=0` condition in the if statement..

Comment: `if( priceArr[x] !=0 && smallest > priceArr[x]) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trying to find the smallest value in an array that isn't 0

The procedure is the same as finding the smallest from an array. On top of that, add a condition to check that the current search is not zero.

```
float smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
for(int x=0; x<priceArr.length; x++) {
    if(smallest < priceArr[x] && priceArr[x] != 0) {    //additional condition here
        smallest = priceArr[x];
    }
}
```

**Note**: The change from `smallest > priceArr[x]` to `smallest < priceArr[x]`.

If your array size is at least 1, you can also set `smallest` as the first array element.

Answer (score 0):

In general case, to compare `double`s with `==`, you may consider error margin in their representation by using an epsilon value.
But this solution is not perfect either.
You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088271/270371).

Default `float` value is `0.0F`.
So, you could so use this condition in the `if` statement :

```
float epsilon = 0.00000001F;

float currentValue = priceArr[x];
if (Math.abs(currentValue) < epsilon && smallest > currentValue ) {
   smallest = currentValue;
}
```

Note that using a local variable to store the `priceArr[x]` value reduces the duplication.

But beware as comparing `float`s by using an epsilon may give matching while the value is not really the `0` value.
For example this :

```
float[] array = new float[5];
array[0] = 0.000000001F;
float epsilon = 0.00000001F;

if (Math.abs(array[0]) < epsilon) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

will produce "match".

If your requirement is only ignoring elements of the array that were not explicitly valued, you should favor `Float` over `float`.
`Float` are by default `null` in an array and you could so test the nullity to ignore the element :

```
Float currentValue = priceArr[x];
if(currentValue != null && smallest > currentValue ) {
   smallest = currentValue;
}
```

Comment: Given that the array seems to contain floats, using `!=` might be dangerous.  Perhaps safer to use `>= 0.0`, assuming no negative values in the array.  If there are then it gets more complex to check.  As you say, integers would simplify things a lot.

Comment: Whoops!  Thanks for the correction.  `> 0.0` is correct.

Comment: @rossum I didn't see that float types were used. My bad. Using `>0` is a way but this means handling only positive values. It is not said in the question.