# Trying to create a boolean expression for when a dot crosses the finish line

Tags: java

Here is the boolean expression that I tried to enter:

```
boolean finish = false;
if (GWINDOW_WIDTH == connectMe.getX())  {
    finish = true;
}
System.out.println(finish);
```

GWINDOW_Width is the width of the window

`connectMe.getX()` is the x coordinate of the dot

I tried to make it so that if the dot touches the edge of the window, the dot finishes the race. However, when running the program, the console window gives the output of "false," even though the dot touched the finish line or the edge of the screen.

Comment: how about printing both GWINDOW_WIDTH and connectMe.getX() and see for yourself if they are actually the same?

Comment: Change to: `if (GWINDOW_WIDTH <= connectMe.getX())  {`

Comment: Thank you @nafas, now I know the values. The dot is touching the edge of the screen at X-coordinate 940, whilst the max width is 1000.

Comment: @user117058 eureka :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the conditional statement to the following for two reasons:

```
if (GWINDOW_WIDTH <= connectMe.getX()) {

}
```

1. If the dot moves slightly passed the exact edge of the screen you current condition will not be trigger.
2. If connectMe.getX() is a float or double, you should test for a range because of the way they are stored. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java) for more on that topic.

Comment: Okay thanks. I found that the dot was touching the edge of the screen at the x-coordinate of 940. So here is the code I am using for it: 'boolean finish = (GWINDOW_WIDTH-60) <= connectMe.getX();
               if (finish) {
              }
               System.out.println("Did the dot finish? : " + finish); ' IT WORKED