# What is the best way to check if a float is 0 in java?

Tags: java

I have used

```
Class CheckFloat {  
    float floatVal;  
    public boolean isFloatZero(){  
        return floatVal==0.0f;  
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Yes. `if(myFloat == 0)`. Simple, understood by all, no need for an additional class and a method...it's got everything you need.

Comment: @Kayaman [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)

Comment: @lexicore checking if a float is 0 is well defined. No need for epsilon here.

Comment: apparently `-0.0f == 0.0f`, thus you do not have to make a separate check

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.signum(x) == 0`. It should never fail.

Answer (score -2):

easily by some checking you can do it 
**First**
if(floatVal==0) sop("it is zero")
**Second**
float b=floatVal;
if(b/floatVal!=1) sop("it is zero"); 
But you should be also aware about the divide by zero error here.