# how execute if condition several times without break inside for loop in java?

Tags: java

In the following code I want to execute the `if` condition inside the outer `for` loop several times, but in the following code it only executes once and executes the steps after it. `binaryHashResult` is an `array` and `innerNode` is a `List`. I want to check if all `values` in `array` exist in `list`.

```
for (int j = 0; j < binaryHashResult.length; j++) 
    if (innerNode[binaryHashResult[j]] == 1.0)
        for (int h = 0; h < m.children.size(); h++) {
            BloomFilterIndex.BFINode<Integer> s=m.children.get(h);
            searchencryptedNode(binaryHashResult, e,  k, s);
        }
```

Comment: How do you know it is only executed once? Did you use a debugger?

Comment: @W.Ambrozic a `for` loop does not _require_ braces, although it's generally a good practice to do so.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]... If it only execute once, then are you ever changing the values in the array? What are the values?

Comment: Might want to check out some debugging tips too https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @W.Ambrozic Not quite. It's not one _line_ but one _statement_. The next statement is an `if` and it (and its contained `for` loop) form the single statement of the outer `for` loop. So the five lines following the initial `for` form its body.

Comment: @user9860564 it's possible your floating point comparison `== 1.0` is failing to perform as you might expect. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java).

Comment: iam using debugging so i noticed that it execude the first (i) when it satisfy ,it complete the next statements. but i want to check all (i) before complete the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

Always wrap blocks of code with {} regardless if the block has only one line.

```
for (int j = 0; j < binaryHashResult.length; j++) 
    if (innerNode[binaryHashResult[j]] == 1.0) {
        for (int h = 0; h < m.children.size(); h++) {
            BloomFilterIndex.BFINode<Integer> s=m.children.get(h);
            searchencryptedNode(binaryHashResult, e,  k, s);
        } // closes inner for loop
   } // closes if
} // closes outer for loop
```