# Math.round and String.format functions does not round up correctly for all float values

Tags: java, android, floating-point, rounding

I tried **Math.round** and **String.format** function to round float/double values.

1) Using Math.round function

```
Math.round(floatValue* 10.0) / 10.0;
```

For floatValue 40.55, result is 40.6 //Correct & Expected result.

For floatValue 30.05, result is 30.0 //Incorrect result. Expected result: 30.1

2) Using String.format function

```
String.format("%.1f", floatValue);
```

For floatValue 40.55 result is 40.6    //Correct & Expected result.

For floatValue 59.65 result is 59.6 //Incorrect result. Expected result: 59.7

Why same function is behaving differently for different float values.

Comment: why do you expect 30.05, to be rounded to 30.6???

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I would expect 30.1 though, there is an inconsistency if both methods are sometimes rounding up and sometimes rounding down

Comment: Sorry for the wrong value. Expected value is 30.1.(Wronly typed while preparing quesion)

Comment: @Sweeper 40.55 -> 40.6 is a round up. 30.05 -> 30.0 is a round down.

Comment: You can't use `Math.round()` to round floats to *N* decimal places. Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/207421.

Comment: For floatValue 40.55, result is 40.6 //Rounding up.

For floatValue 30.05, result is 30.0 //Not rounding.

Answer (score 0):

In can be visualized with

```
    float fv = 30.05f;
    System.out.println((fv));
    System.out.println((fv * 10.0));
    System.out.println(Math.round(fv * 10.0));
    System.out.println(Math.round(fv * 10.0) / 10.0);
```

**result**

```
30.05
300.49999237060547
300
30.0
```

As you can see 30.05 is actually stored as 30.49999237060547 so that is why it *appears* that it is rounding down.  See the more concise explaination by @EricPostpischi in the comments.

See https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/misra/RSPEC-1244

and

[What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)

Comment: Yeah, I also found that [30.05f * 10.0 = 300.49999237060547]. That's the issue. I made it to work by changing code Math.round(this * 10.0f) / 10.0f.

Comment: 30.05 is not stored as 300.49999237060547. First, that is off by a factor of 10, Second, it is not correct to say that one number is stored as another number. If somebody assigned −3 to an `unsigned char`, so that 253 were in the `unsigned char`, we would not say that −3 is “stored as” 253. We recognize that −3 is converted to `unsigned char`, and the result is a different number, 253. Similarly, when `30.05` is read from source code, it is converted to 30.049999237060546875, and then 30.049999237060546875 is stored in `fv`. It is a different number and is **not** a representation of 30.05.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for posting out my typo and also for explaining the problem in a lot better style than I did.