# Compare Float values in python upto 3 decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point

I am using `np.isclose()` to compare 2 float values but for some usecases this doesn't work as expected.

For example

`np.isclose([1000.01], [1000.02])`

returns `True` but it should return `False`.

I cannot make `rtol to 0.0` as I need to compare these values upto 3 decimal places only.

Comment: [There is no general solution for comparing floating-point numbers that contain errors from previous operations.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56040270/298225). Any comparison is application-specific, so you need to provide more context, such as explaining what you are doing and what errors the numbers could contain (bounds on them).

Answer (score 4):

`np.isclose(a, b, rtol=10**-5, atol=10**-8)` checks:

```
np.abs(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * np.abs(b))
```

This means that for your values ~1000 and the defaults it will return `True` if the differences are

```
<= (10**-8 + 10**-5 * np.abs(1000))
<= 0.01000001
```

So your values are within that distance, thus it evaluates to True.

---

If your requirement is

> I need to compare these values up to 3 decimal places only.

Then you don't want a relative tolerance, and instead you want only to specify an absolute tolerance.

```
np.isclose([1000.01, 1000.0013, 1000.0047, 1000.0041, 1000.0045], 
           [1000.02, 1000.0014, 1000.0052, 1000.0052, 1000.005500001],
           rtol=0, atol=10**-3)

#array([False,  True,  True, False, False])
```