# In Java how does internally work == operator, not able to analysis

Tags: java, comparison, operators

In Java how does the `==` operator internally work, I'm not able to analyze

What is the output for the below code

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(0.1 * 2 == 0.2);
        
        System.out.println(0.1 * 3 == 0.3);}
}
```

When I execute this code, I am getting : **true  false** output. How it comes I'm not able to understand. How does JVM calculate the operations?

Comment: Read IEEE standard for floating point.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java

Answer (score -3):

In == operator it checks whether the first value is similar to the second value.
If yes it will print True (the statement is True), if not it will print False (The statement is False)

```
System.out.println(0.1 * 2 == 0.2);
```

In this statement it is asking whether 0.2 is equal to 0.2. Since it is correct it will print True.

Comment: Yes your right, i am agree with your answer but in second case  : 0.1 * 3 == 0.3 , it is also true , it should give output true, why it's giving output as a false