# Asking a predefined value as a float(or string) on an `#if` macro

Tags: c

I want to condition in an `#if` on the float(or string) value of a predefined variable.

As I saw if the value of the predefined variable is a whole number the `#if` is working good. But, if it is a float or a string, the if is not working as expected.

For example:

```
#define _VER_ = 103
#if _VER_ == 103
//Do somthing
#endif
```

The above code is working as expected, the `#if` becomes active/not active according to the `_VER_` value. But, if the `_VER_` value will be set to `1.0.3` or to `"1.0.3"` the `#if` is not working as expected.

For example:

```
#define _VER_ = 1.0.3

#if _VER_ == 1.0.3
//Do somthing
#endif
```

Or this:

```
#define _VER_ = "1.0.3"

#if _VER_ == "1.0.3"
//Do somthing
#endif
```

Both code example are not working as expected, the `#if` stays inactive regardless with the `_VER_` value.

How to make this working properly?

Comment: have you tried printing _VER_?

Comment: `1.0.3` is neither a float, nor a string.

Comment: You don't use `=` in a `#define`. And you can't compare strings in the preprocessor.

Comment: The preprocessor is not the C compiler and doesn't know much about C types. Preprocessor directives can only handle integers. You already found the solution: use `103` instead of `1.0.3` or `"1.0.3"`.

Comment: Add a macro to enable/disable a specific feature instead of trying to use version numbers. `#ifdef HAS_FEATURE_X` ... `#endif`

Answer (score 6):

The pre-processor is not able to do string comparisons at all, and floating point values in `#if` directives are not supported by the standard either. But even if they were comparing floating point is always critical due to rounding issues (keep in mind that you cannot even represent many of such simple numbers like 0.1 exactly as they are periodic in binary), see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java), thus you cannot compare floating points safely either (most likely that's why they are not supported...).

What you could do, though, is having three distinct integral values:

```
#define MAJOR    1
#define MINOR    0
#define REVISION 3
```

Now you can do comparisons on these single values individually like:

```
#if MAJOR > 1 || MAJOR == 1 && MINOR > 0
// anything after 1.0.x
```

What you could do as well is combining these values into a single integer value by shifting them appropriately, e. g.

```
#define VERSION MAKE_VERSION(MAJOR, MINOR, REVISION)
#define MAKE_VERSION(X, Y, Z) MAKE_VERSION_(X, Y, Z)
// intermediate step necessary to resolve the version parts correctly
#define MAKE_VERSION_(X, Y, Z) (X ## lu << 16 | Y ## lu << 8 | Z ## lu)
```

Adding `lu` suffixes: `long` is guaranteed large enough by the standard such that shifting by 16 bit will fit into the type (which is not guaranteed for `int`!). You might experiment with other offsets to make the result fit into int and then leaving out the suffix (e. g. shifting by 8 or 12 instead of 16) or to allow more sub-versions (e. g. by shifting by 20 instead of 16).

Multiplying by 10000 and 100 would do the trick as well and result in more human readable version numbers (in decimal notation at least).

Finally you could create a version string by another macro:

```
#define VERSION_STRING MAKE_VERSION(MAJOR, MINOR, REVISION)
#define MAKE_VERSION(X, Y, Z) MAKE_VERSION_(X, Y, Z)
// intermediate step needed for correct stringification
#define MAKE_VERSION_(X, Y, Z) #X "." #Y "." #Z
```

Side note:

```
#define _VER_ = 103
```

Is plain wrong for two reasons:

1. The pre-processor does nothing else than pure text processing, it is not aware of any C code. The assignment sign (`=`) will be included in text replacement anywhere you use it (so `#if _VER_ == 103` will be expanded to `#if = 103 == 103`).
2. Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a capital character are reserved, using them results in undefined behaviour (note: identifiers with two subsequent underscores – anywhere – as well).

Comment: Turns out I was writing a nearly identical example. Oh well, have a +1 for FGITW.

Comment: Issue with floating point in `#if` preprocessor directive is not with rounding, but it's that floating point is not supported at all. According to standard the controlling expression must be *integer constant expression*.

Comment: Also worth mentioning usage in pre-processor conditional inclusion expressions, such as `#if VERSION >= MAKE_VERSION(1,0,3)`.

Comment: @user694733 Thanks for the hint – do you happen to have by hand the reference to the standard?

Comment: $6.10.1 Conditional inclusion (C17 draft) paragraph 1 mentions the integer constant expression. Technically floating point constants are allowed in general integer constant expression if they are immediately cast, but since operations in paragraph 4 replace keywords with number 0, that is also impossible.

Comment: @IanAbbott Oh, once more stumbling when coming from C++ – it's legal there...

Comment: @Aconcagua `#if VERSION >= MAKE_VERSION(1,0,3)` is legal in C too. My comment was just providing some example usage. (Perhaps you meant to tag user694733, not me?)

Comment: @IanAbbott Nothing written about on [cppreference, C site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional) (in contrast to C++) – which usually is pretty reliable. Incomplete or not up to date?

Comment: An earlier version of your answer had `MAKE_VERSION(1,0,3)` produce an integer constant. That is the one I was referring to for the legality of `#if VERSION >= MAKE_VERSION(1,0,3)`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I know... I meant C++ site explicitly states *macros* being resolved, no word about that on C site, though (which was the reason I removed the `MAKE_VERSION` from the answer – re-added following your comments...).

Comment: C11 (and later) [6.10.1/4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4) covers it: "Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the `defined` unary operator), just as in normal text."

Answer (score 0):

You can split the version up in the way that makes most sense anyway, namely:

```
#define VERS_MAJOR 1
#define VERS_MINOR 0
#define VERS_PATCH 3
```

And then do pre-processor comparisons such as:

```
#if (VERS_MAJOR == 1) && (VERS_MINOR == 0)
   ...
```

If you need to get `1.0.3` as output then convert it to a string literal:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define STR_VERSION(a,b,c) STR(a) "." STR(b) "." STR(c)
#define VERSION STR_VERSION(VERS_MAJOR,VERS_MINOR,VERS_PATCH)
...

puts(VERSION); // prints 1.0.3
```