# Comparing numbers by three decimal points

Tags: java, numbers, compare, decimal, equals

```
public class DecimalComparator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(3.174 , 3.175));
        System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(3.175 , 3.176));
    }
    public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double firstNumber, double secondNumber){
        return (firstNumber >= secondNumber) && ((firstNumber - secondNumber) < 0.001) ? true : (firstNumber < secondNumber) && ((secondNumber - firstNumber) < 0.001) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

I was expecting false on both numbers but got true, false instead. This was the only test which my method didn't pass.

As I said before my test passed 19 other values and couldn't pass this one. Even the examples that I gave are really close.

Comment: So, you want to check, if the two numbers are equal? Why can you not just check for `firstNumber == secondNumber`?

Comment: It seems your comparison missed the mark by `3.175-3.174-0.001` → `-1e-16`. Time to bust out the old [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Geshode I am checking if the numbers are equal by three decimal places like 3.1112 and 3.1113 should be equal but 3.22 and 3.221 should not be equal.

Comment: What you have done is equivalent to comparing floats for exact equality. Which, as you may have noticed, doesn't work right. You have to add a bit of fuzz, e.g. as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java

Comment: BTW such expression like `(test) ? true : false` is like saying if test is `true` it is `true`, otherwise, if it is `false` it is `false` - just use plain `test` (and `Math.abs(firstNumber - secondNumber) < 0.001` would be an alternative, but still show same error due to floating points accuracy) || [@teapot418 somehow I have the impression that OP is already trying to add a *bit of fuzz* with `0.001`]

Comment: @user85421 Thank you, your recommendations made it look nicer.

Comment: @teapot418 I am sorry to be asking alot but is there a way to return (Math.abs(firstNumber - secondNumber) < 0.001); make this work. I looked at the link you sent and there is an epsilon way. But that also failed. BTW I understand now that it is a problem about precision maybe. What's the workaround for problems such as mine?

Comment: According to java's floating point math the difference between 3.174 and 3.175 is 1e-16 less than 0.001. So checking for exactly 0.001 will give you the unwanted 'equal' result. You have to make the threshold very slightly less than 0.001.

Comment: @teapot418 you are a genius. return (Math.abs(firstNumber - secondNumber) < 0.0009999999999998); is the maximum value that I can use. Now I have passed all the tests. How can I select your answer as the right one. I am kinda new, it's my first day.

Comment: Happy to help. This question is closed, there's nothing to accept, we're done here.